# Dump a mysql database to a plaintext (CSV) backup from the command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, csv, backup

I'd like to avoid mysqldump since that outputs in a form that is only convenient for mysql to read.  CSV seems more universal (one file per table is fine).  But if there are advantages to mysqldump, I'm all ears.  Also, I'd like something I can run from the command line (linux).  If that's a mysql script, pointers to how to make such a thing would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output MySQL query results in csv format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

If you can cope with table-at-a-time, and your data is not binary, use the `-B` option to the `mysql` command.  With this option it'll generate TSV (tab separated) files which can import into Excel, etc, quite easily:

```
% echo 'SELECT * FROM table' | mysql -B -uxxx -pyyy database
```

Alternatively, if you've got direct access to the server's file system, use [`SELECT INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) which can generate real CSV files:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM table
```

Comment: thanks!  your second "table" should be "database", right?  no option for CSV instead of TSV that you know of?

Comment: duh - yes, it should have read 'database'.  No, there's no option for CSV, this is the best I know of without using MySQL's built-in 'select into outfile', which _can_ do CSV, but writes the files on the server, not the client.

Comment: how to force overwrite on the output file?

Comment: Note that when a relative path (or simply a filename) is given, the file will appear in your  MYSQL directory, and not your current shell directory (i.e. where `\. file.sql` reads from). As such, depending on your install you will probably find it at `/var/lib/mysql/[db_name]/table.csv`

Answer (score 33):

In MySQL itself, you can specify CSV output like:

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

From http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

Comment: I cant seem to find the dumped file on the directory i specified, why is that?

Comment: @JCm it dumps on the server

Comment: @JCm It dumps to the MySQL data folder by default, which is usually `mysql/data`.

Answer (score 32):

You can dump a whole database in one go with `mysqldump's --tab` option. You supply a directory path and it creates one `.sql` file with the `CREATE TABLE DROP IF EXISTS` syntax and a `.txt` file with the contents, tab separated. To create comma separated files you could use the following:

```
mysqldump --password  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=',' --tab /tmp/path_to_dump/ database_name
```

That path needs to be writable by both the mysql user and the user running the command, so for simplicity I recommend `chmod 777 /tmp/path_to_dump/` first.

Comment: I kept coming back to this answer, it's definitely the best way to export all the tables to a delimited file.

Comment: `mysqldump: You must use option --tab with --fields-...`

Comment: As root: `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost';` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15014385/1707015. In my case I had to take `/var/lib/mysql-files/` (instead of `/tmp/`), set the user to mysql:mysql and set the rights to 777 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737616/1707015.

Answer (score 18):

The select into outfile option wouldn't work for me but the below roundabout way of piping tab-delimited file through SED did:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "SELECT * from tablename" dbname | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > /path/to/file/filename.csv
```

Comment: This command resulted in the letter `t` being replaced with `", "` in the output file. Not exactly what I was after.

Comment: This does not work. It does not generate a csv file

Answer (score 10):

Here is the simplest command for it

```
mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p<password> -e 'select * from databaseName.tableNaame' | sed  's/\t/,/g' > output.csv
```

If there is a comma in the column value then we can generate .tsv instead of .csv with the following command

```
mysql -h<hostname> -u<username> -p<password> -e 'select * from databaseName.tableNaame' > output.csv
```

Comment: For CSV: it works where i just need comma. `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot  -e 'select * from databaseName.tableNaame' | sed  's/\t/,/g' > /tmp/output.csv`
`

Answer (score 3):

If you really need a "Backup" then you also need database schema, like table definitions, view definitions, store procedures and so on.  A backup of a database isn't just the data.

The value of the mysqldump format for backup is specifically that it is very EASY to use it to restore mysql databases.  A backup that isn't easily restored is far less useful.  If you are looking for a method to reliably backup mysql data to so you can restore to a mysql server then I think you should stick with the mysqldump tool.

Mysql is free and runs on many different platforms.  Setting up a new mysql server that I can restore to is simple.  I am not at all worried about not being able to setup mysql so I can do a restore.

I would be far more worried about a custom backup/restore based on a fragile format like csv/tsv failing.  Are you sure that all your quotes, commas, or tabs that are in your data would get escaped correctly and then parsed correctly by your restore tool?

If you are looking for a method to extract the data then see several in the other answers.

Comment: thanks, very helpful! you convinced me. i do have other reasons to want a quick way to get a csv dump via a command line command though. i'm holding out for that for the "accepted answer". (tho i could probably piece it together at this point from the current answers, i guess w/ a mysql script).

Comment: I can see lots of value in having both a backup using the native method and also extracts for other purposes.

Comment: mk-parallel-restore can restore a CSV backup created with mk-parallel dump, so you can get the best of both worlds. In fact, mk-parallel-restore does a better job by ensuring any triggers you have defined are restored last.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below script to get the output to csv files. One file per table with headers.

```
for tn in `mysql --batch --skip-page --skip-column-name --raw -uuser -ppassword -e"show tables from mydb"`
do 
mysql -uuser -ppassword mydb -B -e "select * from \`$tn\`;" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > $tn.csv
done
```

user is your user name, password is the password if you don't want to keep typing the password for each table and mydb is the database name.

Explanation of the script: The first expression in sed, will replace the tabs with "," so you have fields enclosed in double quotes and separated by commas. The second one insert double quote in the beginning and the third one insert double quote at the end. And the final one takes care of the \n.

Comment: This mostly got me where I needed to go but was surprised when the letter "t" was getting replaced with commas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610121/8400969

Comment: And this should say `--skip-column-names` in my version of mysql, as well

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dump the entire db as csv

```
#!/bin/bash

host=hostname
uname=username
pass=password

port=portnr
db=db_name
s3_url=s3://buckera/db_dump/



DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
rm -rf $DATE

echo 'show tables' | mysql -B -h${host} -u${uname} -p${pass} -P${port} ${db} > tables.txt
awk 'NR>1' tables.txt > tables_new.txt

while IFS= read -r line
do
  mkdir -p $DATE/$line
  echo "select * from $line" | mysql -B -h"${host}" -u"${uname}" -p"${pass}" -P"${port}" "${db}" > $DATE/$line/dump.tsv
done < tables_new.txt

touch $DATE/$DATE.fin


rm -rf tables_new.txt tables.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [mk-parallel-dump](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-dump.html) which is part of the ever-useful [maatkit suite of tools](http://www.maatkit.org/). This can dump comma-separated files with the --csv option.

This can do your whole db without specifying individual tables, and you can specify groups of tables in a backupset table.

Note that it also dumps table definitions, views and triggers into separate files. In addition providing a complete backup in a more universally accessible form, it also immediately restorable with [mk-parallel-restore](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-parallel-restore.html)

Comment: This may not be the ideal _backup_ but is completely awesome for SHARING.  Thank you!

Comment: `maatkit` seems to be part of the `percona toolkit` now, but I cannot find corresponding tools.

Answer (score 1):

Two line PowerShell answer:

```
# Store in variable
$Global:csv = (mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost -Ddatabase_name -B -e "SELECT * FROM some_table") `
| ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"

# Out to csv
$Global:csv | Export-Csv "C:\temp\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Boom-bata-boom

`-D` = the name of your database

`-e` = query

`-B` = tab-delimited

Answer (score 1):

There's a slightly simpler way to get all the tables into tab delimited fast:

```
#!/bin/bash
tablenames=$(mysql your_database -e "show tables;" -B |sed "1d")

IFS=$'\n'

tables=($tablenames)

for table in ${tables[@]}; do
        mysql your_database -e "select * from ${table}" -B > "${table}.tsv"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic python script that does the work! You can also choose to export only the headers (column names) or headers & data both.

Just change the database credentials and run the script. It will output all the data to the output folder.

To run the script -

1. Run: pip install mysql-connector-python
2. Change database credentials in the "INPUT" section
3. Run: python filename.py

```
import mysql.connector
from pathlib import Path
import csv 

#========INPUT===========
databaseHost=""
databaseUsername=""
databasePassword=""
databaseName=""
outputDirectory="./WITH-DATA/"
exportTableData=True #MAKING THIS FIELD FALSE WILL STORE ONLY THE TABLE HEADERS (COLUMN NAMES) IN THE CSV FILE
#========INPUT END===========


Path(outputDirectory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host=databaseHost,
  user=databaseUsername,
  password=databasePassword
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("USE "+databaseName)


mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tables = mycursor.fetchall()  

tableNames=[table[0] for table in tables]

print("================================")
print("Total number of tables: "+ str(len(tableNames)))
print(tableNames)
print("================================")

for tableName in tableNames:

    print("================================")
    print("Processing: "+ str(tableName))

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=databaseHost,
        user=databaseUsername,
        password=databasePassword
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("USE "+databaseName)

    if exportTableData:
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tableName)
    else:
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" LIMIT 1")

    print(mycursor.column_names)

    with open(outputDirectory+tableName+".csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile: 
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 

        csvwriter.writerow(mycursor.column_names) 

        if exportTableData:
            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            csvwriter.writerows(myresult)
```

[image: Output folders]

[image: CSV file for each table]

[image: Data inside the CSV]

Answer (score 0):

In 2016, MySQL created the `mysqlsh` utility. This is a new interactive shell for mysql. It can also make backups in `tsv` or `csv` format

The simplest example of use:

```
mysqlsh --mysql -u root -p [password] -h localhost -P 3306 -- util dump-instance /tmp/sample-backup --compression='none' --dialect='csv'
```

In this example, the `compression` and `dialect` parameters are additionally indicated, since by default the dump is created in `tsv` format and compressed in *zsd*

In the `/tmp/sample-backup` directory the `.sql` and `.csv` files for each table with the following names `database_name@table_name` will be created. In the `.sql` file there will be a `CREATE TABLE` command, in the `.csv` file data line.

The first 5 lines of the file `/tmp/sample-backup/sakila@rental@@0.csv`

```
1,"2005-05-24 22:53:30",367,130,"2005-05-26 22:04:30",1,"2006-02-15 17:30:53"
2,"2005-05-24 22:54:33",1525,459,"2005-05-28 19:40:33",1,"2006-02-15 17:30:53"
3,"2005-05-24 23:03:39",1711,408,"2005-06-01 22:12:39",1,"2006-02-15 17:30:53"
4,"2005-05-24 23:04:41",2452,333,"2005-06-03 01:43:41",2,"2006-02-15 17:30:53"
5,"2005-05-24 23:05:21",2079,222,"2005-06-02 04:33:21",1,"2006-02-15 17:30:53"
```

Using `mysqlsh` you can download the created dump back into the database if necessary using the [load-dump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-load-dump.html) command

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-dump-instance-schema.html) on backups via `mysqlsh`

[Simple examples of using](https://sqlbak.com/blog/mysql-command-line-backup-top-5-cli-utilities/#mysqlsh)