# Change all tabs with whitespaces in IntelliJ for 10K+ classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to replace all tab characters in classes by sequences of white-spaces?

Project has 10K+ classes.

Have Community edition IntelliJ, how do I automate this process?

Comment: `find . -name '*.java' -exec sed -i "" 's/  /c/g' {} \;` will do the trick (note: that space after the `s/` is a tab, not a normal space: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/sed-not-recognizing-t-instead-it-is-treating-it-as-t-why)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IntelliJ you can do a find and replace across the entire project by doing ctrl-shift-r, or by going to Edit->Find->Replace In Path, make sure the 'Regular expression' box is ticked, then in the 'Text to find' box enter `\\t` and the 'replace with' box enter four spaces or whatever you want to replace the tabs with

You could do some magic with find and perl:

```
find . -name "*.java" -exec perl -i.bak -pe 's/\t/    /g' "{}" \;
```

This will find all files named *something*.java within the current directory and its subdirs, then call perl to replace all tabs with four spaces, and create a backup of the file before performing this substitution with the extension.bak

Answer (score 1):

You can replace tabs with spaces with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/):

Navigate in the menu bar to "Search→ Find in Files..." and fill the formular like below.

[image]