# How to delimit file with "\t\n" on a Mac

Tags: string, macos, shell, unix, replace

I have a document whose lines are separated by "\t\n".  Records are separated either by "\t", OR by "\n".

Normally, this should be a straigtforward awk query:

```
BEGIN {
   RS='\t\n';
}
{
   print;
   print "Next entry:";
}
```

However, on a Mac, regular expressions do not seem to be supported (maybe I'm not doing something right?) So I tried, `RS="\t\n"`; however, this is interpreted as `RS='\t | \n'`.  Similar problems running awk from the command line:

```
awk 1 RS='\t\n' ORS='abc' input > output
```

replaces the `\t`'s, but leaves the `\n`'s be.

Next try: using `tr`.  This obviously fails for sequence of more than one character-- since `\t` and `\n` are both used individually in the rows.

Next:

```
sed -e '/\t\n/s//NextEntry:/g' input > output
```

However, doesn't work.  Entering any ASCII character sequence instead of \t\n works.

Read the manual.  It says that `\t` is not supported in sed strings.  Fair enough

```
sed -e '/\x9\xa/s//abc/' input > output
```

Still doesn't work.  Idea: use `tr` to replace `\t` and `\n` by characters unused in the input file, use `sed` to change them to what I want, and then `tr` to change the remaining characters back to what they should be.

```
tr: Illegal byte sequence
```

Turns out, that `f6` character makes `tr` just totally fail.

Went through the suggestions in [Sed not recognizing \t instead it is treating it as 't' why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/sed-not-recognizing-t-instead-it-is-treating-it-as-t-why) .  That might work for replacing output strings (except the "Pasting tab into command prompt via CTRL+V" suggestion-- the shell just rejected that paste.), but did not seem to help in my case.

Maybe it's because it's a Mac?  Maybe it's because that's the text I'm looking for, not replacing with?  Maybe it's the combination with `\n`?

Any other suggestions?

UPDATE:

I found thread [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) .  Apparently, I am unable even to replace a `\n` by the string "abc" using the suggestions in that thread.

EDIT: Hex head of source file:

```
5a 20 4e 4f 09 0a 41 53  20 4f 46 20 30 31 2d 30
34 2d 30 35 20 45 4d 50  4c 4f 59 45 45 0a 47 52  
4f 55 50 09 48 49 52 45  20 44 41 54 45 09 53 41 
4c 41 52 59 09 4a 4f 42  20 54 49 54 4c 45 09 0a  
4a 4f 42 20 4c 45 56 45  4c 0a 53 45 52 49 45 53  
09 41 50 50 54 20 54 59  50 45 09 0a 50 41 59 20  
53 54 41 54 55 53 0a f6
```

Comment: Can you provide a copy of your *"unhappy"* file please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell OK, I uploaded the head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, **BSD `awk`, as also used on macOS, doesn't support *multi-character* record separators (`RS`) altogether** (in line with POSIX) - only a *single, literal* character is supported.

**BSD `sed`, as also used on macOS, supports *only* `\n` in regexes** - any other escapes, including *hex* ones (e.g., `\x09`) are *not* supported.
<sup>See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine for a comprehensive comparison of GNU and BSD `sed`.</sup>

Assuming that your `sed` command works in principle, **you can use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)
 (`$'\t'`) to splice a *literal* tab char. into your `sed` script** (assumes `bash` (the macOS default shell), `ksh`, or `zsh`),:

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}' -e '/'$'\t''\n/s//NextEntry:/g'
```

Note that, in order to replace newlines, you must instruct `sed` to read the entire file into memory first, which is what `-e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}'` does (the BSD Sed-compatible form of the common GNU `sed` idiom `:a;$!{N;ba}`).