# How to use sed to replace string that contains slash?

Tags: bash, sed

I wanto replace `# SigningTable  refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable` to `SigningTable  refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`. 
Which means just remove `#`.
I use `sed -i 's/# SigningTable  refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable/ SigningTable  refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable/g' /etc/opendkim.conf`,but doesn't work.
I think it's because `/`,how to use sed to replace string with `/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the delimiter:

```
sed -i 's!TEXT!REPLACE!' file
```

You can use this, if SigningTable appears once in the file:

```
sed '/SigningTable/{s/^# *//}' in
```

or be more specific:

```
sed '\@refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable@{s/^#//}' in
```

Comment: doesn't work .can be reproductive by `yum install opendkim`.

Comment: updated with some other possible solutions. It may be that there is a tab character before the `refile`.

Comment: I use `p` to show the line, nothing appear.

Comment: use a sub-string on that line.

Comment: `SigningTable` appears lots of times.You are right, it's `tab character`, when I copy to `windows`,`tab` become `space`.Then, any solution for `tab in sed`.

Comment: try `\t`, if that fails look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2610121/390913, or you can use a `.` instead of a tab.

Comment: you can skip parts of the string with `.*` too, for example `SigningTable.*/etc/...`