# Converting Tab to spaces in linux ussing sed

Tags: linux, sed

I found a command that suggests is: `sed 's/t\ /g' file1 > file2`, but nothing is happening
I appreciate your help

File1

```
> NL000414570133    3   317 59  50  2005autumn
> IT023990159886    2   508 64  54  2008winter
> IT019990368451    9   411 72  54  2007autumn
> IT028990115247    17  424 47  35  2007spring
> IT024000416093    2   413 53  49  2004spring
> IT017990395438    14  2010    53  42  2011spring
> IT028990024896    2   469 52  42  2005autumn
> NL000353035324    2   348 63  48  2003summer
```

File2

```
NL000414570133 3 317 59 50 2005autumn
IT023990159886 2 508 64 54 2008winter
IT019990368451 9 411 72 54 2007autumn
IT028990115247 17 424 47 35 2007spring
IT024000416093 2 413 53 49 2004spring
IT017990395438 14 2010 53 42 2011spring
IT028990024896 2 469 52 42 2005autumn
```

Comment: `sed 's/\t/ /g' file1 > file2`?

Comment: @wiktor is not functioning correctly

Comment: `sed $"s/\t/ /g" file1 > file2`?

Comment: does not work either

Comment: Please post an [MCVE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, provide the sed and OS details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610115/why-is-sed-not-recognizing-t-as-a-tab

```sed "s/$(echo '\t')/ /g" file1 > file2```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` instead. If you force it to rebuild the record by assigning to a field, it will collapse any sequence of whitespace to a single space.

```
awk '{$1 = $1; print}' file1 > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

**TR**anslating one char to another is the job that `tr` exists to do:

```
$ tr '\t' ' ' < file
NL000414570133 3 317 59 50 2005autumn
IT023990159886 2 508 64 54 2008winter
IT019990368451 9 411 72 54 2007autumn
IT028990115247 17 424 47 35 2007spring
IT024000416093 2 413 53 49 2004spring
IT017990395438 14 2010 53 42 2011spring
IT028990024896 2 469 52 42 2005autumn
NL000353035324 2 348 63 48 2003summer
```