# What's the best way to dump a MYSQL table to CSV?

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dump a mysql database to a plaintext (CSV) backup from the command line.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467452/dump-a-mysql-database-to-a-plaintext-csv-backup-from-the-command-line)

I prefer python, but if mysqldump works...then how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)