# Python multiprocessing with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, multiprocessing

I've Googled this topic a lot, but cannot find a solution which fits my needs :(

I have a MySQL DB with a table containing e-mail adresses (10,000+).

I would like to run a batch job on them every 5 minute.

So I'll guess Python is a good choice for retrieving the resultset from MySQL and then call a command-line with the e-mail address' as arguments.

How do I do this the best way? I'm think of getting the entire resultset from MySQL and then have a bunch of workes calling the command-line with the arguments until there aren't anymore e-mail address. Can this be done in a simple, yet stable, way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the multiprocessing module like this :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool()    # let python choose the optimal number of processes (= number of CPU cores)
def treat_email(email_adress):
    # do the stuff you need with email address

email_addresses = grab_the_list_from_mysql()  # something like "select mail from my_user_table"

p.map(treat_email, email_addresses)    # this will treat all the emails in the X processes
```

Comment: I've tried to modify your example to a real one:
`code`
from multiprocessing import Pool
import MySQLdb

p = Pool()

email_addresses = []

def treat_email(email_adress):
    print "%s" % (email_adress)

conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "YYY", passwd = "XXX", db = "ZZZ")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute ("SELECT email FROM data GROUP BY email")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    email_addresses.append(row[0])
cursor.close()
conn.close()

p.map(treat_email, email_addresses)
`code`

But it fails with AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'treat_email'

Comment: It works with: if __name__ == '__main__':

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using an ORM module you could dump the emails in a CSV file:

```
SELECT name, address
FROM email
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/emails.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

From: [Dump a mysql database to a plaintext (CSV) backup from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467452/dump-a-mysql-database-to-a-plaintext-csv-backup-from-the-command-line/467528#467528)

And post process the CSV file in python:

```
import csv
data = csv.reader(open('/tmp/emails.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',')
for row in data:
    name, address = row
    print '%s <%s>' % (name, address)
```

CSV File Reading and Writing: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

When your dealing with very large files you might want to use the file.readlines() function to prevent Python from reading the whole file into memory:

```
with open('/tmp/emails.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        name, address = line.split(',')
        print '%s <%s>' % (name, address)
```