# Which are the proper privileges to mysqldump for the Error Access denied when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'.?

Tags: windows, mysql

backup user has BackupAdmin role and ALL privileges (object rights, DDL, GRANT).

```
cmd> mysqldump --routines=TRUE --tab=C:\tmp -h localhost -u backup -pbackup schemalocal
cmd> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'backup'@'%' (using password: YES) when executing 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE'
```

The only way to make it work is to give DBA role to backup account, but that is a security risk so I want to give it only the neccesary rights.
Which are them?

Comment: Are you sure, that the password is correct? For SELECT INTO OUTFILE there is just one privelege necessary: SELECT_PRIV

Comment: The password is correct because I tried with exactly the same code but after give it DBA role and it worked fine.

Comment: I found out that Workbench doesn't allow to backup permissions to GRANT FILE.
Which is the command to do it for an user?
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/grant.html

Answer (score 20):

You need the [`FILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_file) privilege in order to be allowed to use `SELECT...INTO OUTFILE`, which seems to be what `mysqldump --tab` uses to generate the tab-separated dump.

This privilege is [global](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-global-privileges), which means it may only be granted "`ON *.*`" :

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'backup'@'%';
```

Comment: And the reason for needing these privileges is that the files are created on the **server** if you are running the command against a remote DB server. Beware of killing hosts by filling up disk space.

Comment: This did not work for me, nor did changing AppArmor nor did running as root. Only creating /tmp/mysql-dump/ then chown -R 777 /tmp/mysql-dump/ and running mysqldump into that folder.