# Exporting all data from MySQL database to spreadsheets

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, spreadsheet, dump

So, I've got a MySQL database consisting of a bunch of tables that I want to give to my uncle.

Problem is, he doesn't know much about computers, so I can't just hook him up with the database.

Instead, I would like to extract all the data from the database into a more readable format, e.g. Excel spreadsheets.

I've tried mysqldump, but that just gives me a *.sql file which doesn't help much.

Any ideas?

Comment: mysqldump --batch will write in TSV form instead of SQL statements.  phpMyAdmin is handy if you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have command line, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467465/679449) explains how to dump into a tab delimited and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/467528/679449) how to dump into a comma delimited file. You can then import the tab delimited file into Excel.

Alternatively, you can use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to export to `*.csv` if you have PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHPmyadmin allows you to Export to many different formats - why don't you access your database through that?