# Django database; how to download huge data in csv format

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, django-models

I have setup my database in Django in which I have huge amount of data. The task is to download all the data at a time in csv format. The problem which I am facing here is when the data size (in number of table rows) is upto 2000, I am able to download it but when number of rows reaches to more than 5k, it throws an error, "Gateway timeout". How to handle such issue. There is no table indexing as of now.
Also, when there is 2K data available, it takes around 18sec to download. So how this can be optimized.

Comment: We can't know how it can be optimized because you haven't shown us any code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the code that is generating the CSV is as optimized as possible.

Next, the gateway timeout is coming from your front end proxy; so simply increase the timeout there.

However, this is a temporary reprieve - as your data set grows, this timeout will be exhausted and you'll keep getting these errors.

The permanent solution is to trigger a separate process to generate the CSV in the background, and then download it once its finished. You can do this by using [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [rq](http://python-rq.org/) which are both ways to queue tasks for execution (and then collect the results at a later time).

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently using HttpResponse from django.http then you could try using StreamingHttpResponse instead.

Failing that, you could try querying the database directly. For example, if you use the MySql database backend, these answers might help you: 
[dump-a-mysql-database-to-a-plaintext-csv-backup-from-the-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467452/dump-a-mysql-database-to-a-plaintext-csv-backup-from-the-command-line)

As for the speed of the transaction, you could experiment with other database backends. However, if you need to do this often enough for the speed to be a major issue then there may be something else in the larger process which should be optimized instead.