# downloaded CSV reports overloading servers, how can I grab thousands of records efficiently?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

Say I have a page that lets you download CSV reports of your user account's comments, which can have thousands of records. Is there a faster way to go through each users comments? Right now I'm just doing a simple loop.

```
@user.comments.each do comment
 # create csv
end
```

Comment: Storing data in a database instead of csv files would be a good start.

Comment: @DanBracuk it is in a database. There's page where you can download that data to a CSV file.

Comment: Which `DBMS` you are using. In `SQL SERVER` we can `BCP` utility to generate CSV. It is very efficient you dont have to loop through each record

Comment: @Prdp using mysql2

Comment: I agree with @Prdp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467452/dump-a-mysql-database-to-a-plaintext-csv-backup-from-the-command-line execute raw SQL query to dump CSV in one go!

Comment: You should cut some slack if the database is small as there won't be any performance issues. It will be an extra overhead which dosen't worth your time at this stage. But as DB size grows huge then you can give a serious thought to it.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of DB specific queries to dump straight to CSV, and assuming you really are only dumping a single user's comments at once I would use `pluck` to avoid the overhead of instantiating all those AR objects.  It also means you could limit the columns returned to only those that truly need to be exported.

```
@user.comments.pluck(:id, :body).each do |comment|
  # add to csv here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
require 'csv'
sql = "Select * from comments"
records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
CSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  records.each do |rec|
    csv << rec
  end
end
```

Should be a couple of orders of magnitude faster than creating an AR object for each row.  Haven't tested this code, but you get the idea.