# BASH MySQL Query to Comma Separated File

Tags: bash, mysql, csv

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

MYSQLHOST="mysql.remote-host.com"
MYSQLDB="mysqldb"
MYSQLTABLE="table"
MYSQLUSER="user"
MYSQLPASS="pass"
MYSQLDUMP="Report/report.csv"
LOG="Report/report.log"

MYSQLOPTS="--user=${MYSQLUSER} --password=${MYSQLPASS} --host=${MYSQLHOST} ${MYSQLDB}"


echo "Report Begin: $(date)"
 echo "MySQL Dump Begin: $(date)" >> ${LOG}
  echo "SELECT ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at, ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_options FROM ${MYSQLTABLE} WHERE ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_id=1 ORDER BY ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at" | mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} > ${MYSQLDUMP}
 echo "MySQL Dump End: $(date)" >> ${LOG}
echo "Report Successful: $(date)"
```

This ouputs my MySQL Query into a "**TAB**" separated file *report.csv*.  However, I need to have it output to a "**COMMA**" separated file.  I realize I could create another script to convert this file from TAB to COMMA separated, however, I'd rather save the step if I can.  So how can I have MySQL dump the file in comma separated format?

EDIT:
I did find this solution: [How do you output MySQL query results in csv format (to the screen, not to a file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707473/how-do-you-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format-to-the-screen-not-to-a-file)

However I can't seem to get it to work:

```
echo "SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at, ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_options) FROM ${MYSQLTABLE} WHERE ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_id=1 ORDER BY ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at" | mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} > ${MYSQLDUMP}
```

Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple perl 1-liner that seems to do the trick:

```
perl -F"\t" -lane 'print join ",", map {s/"/""/g; /^[\d.]+$/ ? $_ : qq("$_")} @F '
```

-[Perl Script](http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=55)

So the line in my script looks like this:

```
        echo "SELECT ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at, ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_options FROM ${MYSQLTABLE} WHERE ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_id=1 ORDER BY ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at" | mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} | perl -F"\t" -lane 'print join ",", map {s/"/""/g; /^[\d.]+$/ ? $_ : qq("$_")} @F ' > ${MYSQLDUMP}
```

Thanks for all the help, Especially from Bill Karwin, I wanted to add a VoteUp to your answer but I don't have enough reputation :(
Once I get more rep, I'll circle back and vote your answer up.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:

```
echo "SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at, ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_options) FROM ${MYSQLTABLE} WHERE ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_id=1 ORDER BY ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at" | \
mysql ${MYSQLOPTS}  | tr '\t' ',' > ${MYSQLDUMP}
```

The [`tr`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr+1) command replaces one char with another.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) SQL query that outputs to a comma-separated file:

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

---

Re comments:  Fair enough, the `INTO OUTFILE` syntax writes to a file on the database server host, not the host where the shell script and the mysql client is running.

The mysql client doesn't have a csv output mode, it only has the bars-and-dashes tabular format (with the `--table` or `-t` flags), tab-separated format (with the `--batch` or `-B` flags), HTML format (`--html` or `-H`) and XML (`--xml` or `-X`).

If you have content in your database that contains tabs, then either convert tabs to something else using the `REPLACE()` SQL function, or else output in one of the other formats and try to convert that to csv:

```
mysql ... --table --skip-column-names |
sed -e 's/  *|  */,/g' \
    -e 's/^|  *//' \
    -e 's/  *|$//' \
    -e '/^+--/d'
```

Comment: That writes to a file on the server, not to standard out.

Comment: @staticsan: Yes you're right.  But notice "`MYSQLHOST=localhost`" in the OP's question.

Comment: I can't get it to work:   echo "SELECT ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at, ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_options INTO OUTFILE 'Report/tmp2.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM ${MYSQLTABLE} WHERE ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_id=1 ORDER BY ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at" | mysql ${MYSQLOPTS} > ${MYSQLDUMP}
    I get:
./report.sh: line 28: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./report.sh: line 33: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Remove the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` clause.  You don't need fields enclosed by double-quotes, and that's probably what's causing the unbalanced quotes in your shell script.

Comment: staticsan has a point... I did put "localhost" in there, but that's not quite the truth, the MYSQL DB is stored on a REMOTE server, so this won't work :(  I get the following when I tryed it after removing OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY: ERROR 1045 (28000) at line 1: Access denied for user 'user'@'123.456.789.0/255.255.254.0' (using password: YES)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about that to begin with, I didn't think it was going to be a problem.

Comment: I Edited my initial question to reflect "Remote Host"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another script to do that. Just change:

```
> ${MYSQLDUMP}
```

at the end of your line to read:

```
| sed 's/\x09/,/g' > ${MYSQLDUMP}
```

But you need to be careful that your data doesn't have commas in it or they'll be mis-recognized by whatever uses the CSV file (but you may have that problem with tabs already).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work :(
The "product_options" field contains items that get pickedup by the sed command and breaks them into new columns :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
SELECT ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at, ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_options INTO outfile '${MYSQLDUMP}' FROM ${MYSQLTABLE} FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' WHERE ${MYSQLTABLE}.product_id=1 ORDER BY ${MYSQLTABLE}.created_at
```

Comment: Look at the comments left in Bill Karwin's Answer.
I can't because it's a remote server that hosts the mysql db, and I don't have Read/Write privileges.