# Extract Data from CSV in shell script (Sed, AWK, Grep?)

Tags: shell, csv, sed, awk, grep

I need to extract some data from a CSV file.  The CSV is a 2 column file with multiple records.  The first column is the date, the second column is the data that needs to be extracted.  The first row of the CSV file is the column headers, so it can be skipped.  And I've already created the column header for the extracted data's csv file, so theres no need for that, I'll simply use >> to import the data into it.

Here is 1 record/line (of many) in the CSV file:

```
"2009-09-20 00:12:37","a:2:{s:15:""info_buyRequest"";a:5:{s:4:""uenc"";s:116:""aHR0cDovL3N0b3JlLmZvcmdldGhhbmdvdmVycy5jb20vcGF0Y2hlcy9pbmRpdmlkdWFsLXBhdGNoZXMvZnJlZS1zYW1wbGUuaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,"";s:7:""product"";s:1:""1"";s:15:""related_product"";s:0:"""";s:7:""options"";a:13:{i:17;s:2:""59"";i:16;s:2:""50"";i:15;s:2:""49"";i:14;s:2:""47"";i:13;s:2:""41"";i:12;s:2:""34"";i:11;s:2:""25"";i:10;s:2:""23"";i:9;s:2:""19"";i:8;s:2:""17"";i:7;s:2:""12"";i:6;s:1:""9"";i:5;s:1:""5"";}s:3:""qty"";i:1;}s:7:""options"";a:13:{i:0;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:25:""How did you hear about us"";s:5:""value"";s:22:""Friend / Family Member"";s:11:""print_value"";s:22:""Friend / Family Member"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""17"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""59"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:1;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:3:""Age"";s:5:""value"";s:5:""21-24"";s:11:""print_value"";s:5:""21-24"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""16"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""50"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:2;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:14:""Marital Status"";s:5:""value"";s:9:""UnMarried"";s:11:""print_value"";s:9:""UnMarried"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""15"";s:11:""option_type"";s:5:""radio"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""49"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:3;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:3:""Sex"";s:5:""value"";s:6:""Female"";s:11:""print_value"";s:6:""Female"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""14"";s:11:""option_type"";s:5:""radio"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""47"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:4;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:10:""Occupation"";s:5:""value"";s:7:""Student"";s:11:""print_value"";s:7:""Student"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""13"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""41"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:5;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:9:""Education"";s:5:""value"";s:16:""College Graduate"";s:11:""print_value"";s:16:""College Graduate"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""12"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""34"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:6;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:16:""Household Income"";s:5:""value"";s:7:""30K-50K"";s:11:""print_value"";s:7:""30K-50K"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""11"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""25"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:7;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:23:""Do You Take Supplements"";s:5:""value"";s:2:""No"";s:11:""print_value"";s:2:""No"";s:9:""option_id"";s:2:""10"";s:11:""option_type"";s:5:""radio"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""23"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:8;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:40:""How would you rank your typical hangover"";s:5:""value"";s:4:""Mild"";s:11:""print_value"";s:4:""Mild"";s:9:""option_id"";s:1:""9"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""19"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:9;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:51:""What type of establishments do you typically prefer"";s:5:""value"";s:10:""Nightclubs"";s:11:""print_value"";s:10:""Nightclubs"";s:9:""option_id"";s:1:""8"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""17"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:10;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:40:""How often do you usually go out per week"";s:5:""value"";s:3:""1-2"";s:11:""print_value"";s:3:""1-2"";s:9:""option_id"";s:1:""7"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:2:""12"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:11;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:49:""How many drinks do you typically consume per week"";s:5:""value"";s:3:""6-8"";s:11:""print_value"";s:3:""6-8"";s:9:""option_id"";s:1:""6"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:1:""9"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}i:12;a:7:{s:5:""label"";s:53:""How would you prefer to buy our Products"";s:5:""value"";s:6:""Online"";s:11:""print_value"";s:6:""Online"";s:9:""option_id"";s:1:""5"";s:11:""option_type"";s:9:""drop_down"";s:12:""option_value"";s:1:""5"";s:11:""custom_view"";b:0;}}}"
```

The Output should be the data found here:

- ""print_value";s:**?**:""**{DATA}**""

Were the **?** is a number, and **{DATA}** is the data being extracted.

So the output for example of this 1 record would be:

```
"2009-09-20 00:12:37","Friend / Family Member","21-24","UnMarried","Female","Student","College Graduate","30K-50K","No","Mild","Nightclubs","1-2","6-8","Online"
```

I am not proficient in Sed,AWK, or Grep, but I know it can be done using one of these tools if not all three.  Any help or nudges in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: `sed` would be your tool of choice, but where's the data coming from? The second field looks to me like a PHP serialised array, perhaps PHP would be a better choice of tool for the job?

Comment: what you really seem to be asking for is a way to parse the serialized PHP data structure, rather than just plain CSV.

Comment: The data has already been extracted from a MySQL DB of a Magento store.  See my last question for further info on how I extracted it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452336/bash-mysql-query-to-comma-separated-file

Comment: Bash is not the right tool for this job -- see just how convoluted the closer-to-complete solutions below are, and there's no guarantee that they hit all the corner cases. Use a language with a longstanding, QAed, peer-reviewed CSV library available (Python has on in its standard library, for instance) rather than trying to hack something together without.

Comment: @BassKozz Have you tried using `grep -o` ? `grep -o '""print_value"";s:[0-9]*:""[^"]*""'`

Comment: Or to get it exactly as you have it formatted at the end: `grep -o '""print_value"";s:[0-9]*:""[^"]*""' your.csv | sed 's/""print_value""[,]*;s:[0-9]*:"//g;s/""$/",/g' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/,$//'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use PHP to de-serialize the structure.
However, here's a quick and dirty version of what you want using **sed** and **tr**. Certainly you can do this much much better:

```
cat file.csv | \
tr ",;" "\n" | \
sed -e 's/[asbi]:[0-9]*[:]*//g' -e '/^[{}]/d' -e 's/""//g' -e '/^"{/d' | \
sed -n -e '/^"/p' -e '/^print_value$/,/^option_id$/p' | \
sed -e '/^option_id/d' -e '/^print_value/d' -e 's/^"\(.*\)"$/\1/' | \
tr "\n" "," | \
sed -e 's/,\([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\)/\n\1/g' -e 's/,$//' | \
sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' -e 's/,/","/g'
```

The explanation:

- split by commas and semicolons
- remove remove the php structure syntax s:X:Y, b:X, ... and remove lines starting with { or } or "{
- extract the section from print_value to the next option_id, also keep the date (line start with ")
- remove those labels (print and option), and remove quotations around the date
- concat all lines with commas
- seperate lines (starting with date pattern), and remove extra comma at end
- add quotations around all fields

Wow, I know it's embarrassing :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my anwser:

```
cat TestData \
    | grep -o -P "print_value\"\";.*?:\"\".*?\"\";" \
    | perl -pe 's|print_value.*:\"\"(.*?)\"\";|\1|'
```

The first line show the data (stored in TestData).

The second line asks grep to separate each match from print_value to the nearest '"";'.
Notice that I use '.*?' for non greedy match (needs to use '-P' with it).

The last line use perl to strip all un-needed. See that I use '(.*?)' to match the needed group and use '\1' to show the group.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This just put each answer on it's own line.  1 column.  Doesn't work for a comma-separated CSV.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the part to put them back together. This is just the extracting part.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sed oneliner:

```
sed -nr 's/^([^,]+),(.*)$/\2@%@\1/;:a;s/""print_value"";s:[0-9]+:""([^"]+)""(.*)$/\2,"\1"/;ta;s/^.*@%@//p' <source
```

Basically extract the data and append it to the end of the line using a unique delimiter '@%@'.

When the loop/substitute construct fails (i.e. no more data), throw away what is left of the original line leaving the data nicely formatted.