# How can I suppress the hyphens in the output of a mysql query (cmd line)

Tags: mysql

When I run a mysql query at the command line, the output is encapsulated with hyphens, or bars and plus signs...

```
mysql -h myhost -u me -pmypw -N thedb -e "select 1 from table1"
```

I get...

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

How can I get rid of the hyphens, or bars and plus signs ?

Thanks !

Bonus points if you can tell me how to escape backticks in the command as they are needed to specify a column name that someone decided to name with a reserve word...

```
mysql -h myhost -u me -pmypw -N thedb -e "select `trigger` from table1"
```

I tried \ and `` and '`' and whatever else I could think of.  No luck.

I got around this (sort of) by creating a view of the table that used a non-reserve word in place of 'trigger'

Comment: For the first question, will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640287/change-output-format-for-mysql-command-line-results-to-csv

Comment: For the second, show how you used the backslash to escape the character. But remember that simply putting "\`" inside the string will not work -- you also have to escape the backslash. Try "...\\\`..." inside the string. So: mysql -h myhost ...... "SELECT \\\`trigger\\\` FROM table1"

Comment: % mysql -h myhost -u me_rw -pmypw -N -B mydb -e "select * from try"
abc
% mysql -h myhost -u me -pmypw -N -B mydb -e "select `trigger` from try"
trigger: Command not found.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual (blah, blah)
% mysql -h myhost -u me -pmypw -N -B mydb -e "select \\`trigger\\` from try"
trigger\: Command not found.
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\\'.

Comment: The -B worked great BTW, thanks !