# linebreak in CSV

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

In CSV file that export from mysql, a few data has linebreak

```
This
is
Sunday
```

into

```
This is Sunday
```

How do I replace those linebreak into "\n" character which I can parse at later time. It seem the code below does not replace correcly. Parse

```
result = result.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g, "\\n");
```

Next, to split into array

```
var splitRegExp:RegExp = /\r*\n+|\n*\r+/gm;
var lines:Array = result.split(splitRegExp);
```

Comment: You can avoid the problem by doing a better export. See [1119312](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119312/mysql-export-into-outfile-csv-escaping-chars)

Answer (score 1):

In Flex/ActionScript the '\n' character is already a line break.  You don't need to replace it w/ anything.  I've used something like this to turn line breaks into a comma separated list:

```
var lineFeedRegEx : RegExp = new RegExp('\n|\r|(\r\n)' ,'ig');
results = results.replace(lineFeedRegEx , ',');
```

It should support all possible iterations of carriage return (\r) / line feed (\n).  From there you could be able to split it into an array:

```
var lines:Array = result.split(',');
```

However, I Bet you can cut out the middleman completely:

```
var lineFeedRegEx : RegExp = new RegExp('\n|\r|(\r\n)' ,'ig');
var lines:Array = result.split(lineFeedRegEx);
```