# fopen with cron job

Tags: php, cron

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have a php script which is supposed to be executed with a cron job, extract data from a database and put it in a csv file.
When I run it from the browser, it works just fine so I'm sure my query is correct. But, when I use cron job, it returns "**No input file specified.**" and doesn't write to the file.

Here's my code:

CRON:

> /home/ACCOUNT_NAME/public_html/directory/report.sh

*report.sh*

```
php -q /home/ACCOUNT_NAME/public_html/directory/report.php
php -q /home/ACCOUNT_NAME/public_html/directory/report_mail.php
```

*report.php*

```
<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_un", "my_pw") ;

    if(!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()) ;
        }
    mysql_select_db("my_db", $con) ;

if (!function_exists('fputcsv')){
        function fputcsv($objFile,$arrData,$strDelimiter=',',$strEnclose='"') {
            $strNewLine="\n";
            $strToWrite = '';
            foreach ($arrData as $strCell){
                //Test if numeric
                if (!is_numeric($strCell)){
                    //Escape the enclose
                    $strCell = str_replace($strEnclose,$strEnclose.$strEnclose,$strCell);
                    //Not numeric enclose
                    $strCell = $strEnclose . $strCell . $strEnclose;
                }
                if ($strToWrite==''){
                    $strToWrite = $strCell;
                } else {
                    $strToWrite.=  $strDelimiter . $strCell;
                }
            }
            $strToWrite.=$strNewLine;
            fwrite($objFile,$strToWrite);
        }
}

// CUT - MY QUERY HERE


$fp = fopen("/reports/report.csv" , "w+");

foreach ($list as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, split(',', $line));
}
?>
```

The csv file should be stored under

> /home/ACCOUNT_NAME/public_html/directory/reports/report.csv

What am I missing here? TIA

Comment: You need to add a base path to your fopen path, currently the path will be parsed from root.

Comment: $fp = fopen("/reports/report.csv" , "w+"); check '/reports/report.csv'

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4):

You're not saving to the correct dir. Instead do

```
$fp = fopen(__DIR__ . "/reports/report.csv" , "w+");
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when you start your `fopen()` argument with `/`, you're going to the server root, not the web root. So instead, you either need to give `fopen()` the full path to the file, or dynamically retrieve the current directory like so:

```
$this_directory = dirname( __FILE__ );
$fp = fopen($this_directory . "/reports/report.csv" , "w+");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fp = fopen("/reports/report.csv" , "w+");
```

This won't write to where you're expecting the file to go. It will try to create it in the `reports` directory at the root of the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be off-topic, but MySQL is able to directly output query results to a CSV file using 'INTO OUTFILE'.

*note* MySQL should be running on the same server as the desired output file location

See here for an example:
[MySQL export into outfile : CSV escaping chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119312/mysql-export-into-outfile-csv-escaping-chars)