# MYSQL Query results exported to .csv

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, cron

How would I go about having my sql query results exported to a .csv file? The goal is to automate this process, the query would pull records from the previous day and then export them to a directory of my choosing. If possible, I'd even like to have the date added to the filename so it doesn't automatically overwrite the previous day's results.

here is the query :

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, g.date, g.date_mod, g.status, cree_par, modifier_par
FROM glpi_tickets g , (select id, concat(realname , ' ' , firstname)
cree_par from glpi_users ) c, (select id, concat(realname , ' ' ,
firstname) modifier_par from glpi_users) m
where users_id_recipient <> users_id_lastupdater
and users_id_recipient = c.id
and users_id_lastupdater = m.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOWTOs at:

https://ariejan.net/2008/11/27/export-csv-directly-from-mysql/,

[MySQL export into outfile : CSV escaping chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119312/mysql-export-into-outfile-csv-escaping-chars)

and

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-export-data-csv/

If you want to export to Excel .xls or .xlsx install PHPtoExcel or PHPExcel.

There is one for PEAR and a NON-PEAR version.  The later works better!