# How to export MySQL table into CSV without newlines in VARCHAR fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I want to export the contents of a table into a CSV file but skip any \n or \r that might be present in the VARCHAR columns.

I want to have one line in the CSV per row in the table.

I've used SELECT INTO OUTFILE statement for exporting before, I don't know how to get rid of the newlines and carriage returns in the export itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: possibly answered by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119312/mysql-export-into-outfile-csv-escaping-chars