# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - only one row gets inserted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have recently crossed over from SQL and still having some trouble time to time. Could anyone help me please with this blocker. I am sure this is some silly mistake I am making but I can't pass it.

Then I have created table:

```
create table FFX_DCM_RawData (
    ID int,
    Campaign varchar (256),
    Site_DFA varchar (256),
    Placement varchar (256),
    Report_Date varchar (256),
    Creative varchar (256),
    Ad varchar (256),
    Impression integer,
    Clicks integer,
    Media_Cost decimal (5,2),
    MobileClickToCall_Buy_PostClick integer,
    MobileClickToCall_Buy_PostView integer,
    MobileClickToCall_Rent_PostClick integer,
    MobileClickToCall_Rent_PostView integer,
    MobileEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostClick integer,
    MobileEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostView integer,
    MobileEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostClick integer,
    MobileEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostView integer,
    DesktopClickToReveal_Buy_PostClick integer,
    DesktopClickToReveal_Buy_PostView integer,
    DesktopClickToReveal_Rent_PostClick integer,
    DesktopClickToReveal_Rent_PostView integer,
    DesktopEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostClick integer,
    DesktopEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostView integer,
    DesktopEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostClick integer,
    DesktopEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostView integer
);
```

and inserted via INFILE...

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Users//Jakub//Desktop//DCM Data_All Channels.csv' INTO TABLE test.FFX_DCM_RawData
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (Id, Campaign, Site_DFA, Placement, Report_Date,
Creative, Ad, Impression, Clicks, Media_Cost, MobileClickToCall_Buy_PostClick, MobileClickToCall_Buy_PostView,
MobileClickToCall_Rent_PostClick, MobileClickToCall_Rent_PostView, MobileEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostClick,
MobileEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostView, MobileEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostClick, MobileEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostView,
DesktopClickToReveal_Buy_PostClick, DesktopClickToReveal_Buy_PostView, DesktopClickToReveal_Rent_PostClick,
DesktopClickToReveal_Rent_PostView, DesktopEmailEnquiry_Buy_PostClick, DesktopEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostClick,
DesktopEmailEnquiry_Rent_PostView
);
```

but the result is always that only one row gets inserted. Anyone knows where I am going wrong?

Comment: Add `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'`

Comment: The better choice is to use HeidiSQL http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=import_textfile

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but this is defaults in heidisql while csv upload

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ESCAPED BY '"'
```

Also if you using excel you can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2859026/2534236) as well

Comment: Thanks for your responds however even adding '\r\n' didn't solve my issue. Not sure what else I should try