# MySQL export text fields with special characters to outfile

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export some query results to a CSV or TAB delimited file. One of the fields is a text blob which includes special characters, possibly including single and double quotation marks (`"`, `'`), newlines (`\n`) and tabs (`\t`).

```
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| col1 | col2 | text                                                   |
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 |  foo | Oh hey why not "this" or t'is                          |
or a newline while we are at it |
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the query I am using, with `\t` instead of `,` for TAB delimited files.

```
SELECT col1, col2, text
FROM   mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/foo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This neither works with CSV or TAB delimited files, as any commas or quotes or tabs in a text field end up splitting the text blob across multiple lines and/or columns in any exported file.

**Actual question:**

Is there any way to escape special characters like `", ', \t, \n` in the text field and write to a CSV or TAB file, or do these need to be replaced before attempting to write to a file?

If these should be replaced, I would try to start with the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119312/mysql-export-into-outfile-csv-escaping-chars) using the `REPLACE` function, but I'd prefer something that preserves the original text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't figure out how to escape all special characters, so here's a solution using `REPLACE` on the offending characters:

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
       replace(replace(replace(text, '\n', 'n'), ',', '\,'), '\"', '\'') text 
FROM   mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/foo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete all special characters using regular expression.

```
SELECT col1, col2, 
   REGEXP_REPLACE(columnName, '[^\\x20-\\x7E]', '') text
FROM   mytable
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/foo.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```