# Can't find the file created by outfile in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-io

I am using the following query to create a CSV file

```
SELECT email INTO OUTFILE "mydata.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM users;
```

But i am unable to find the mydata.csv file anywhere when i am searching through filezilla.

Any idea where this file is getting stored?

The query runs successfully without any errors! Any Help?

Comment: It is most likely in the MySQL data directory (like /var/lib/mysql). To specify a directory use a full path like `INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mydata.csv'`

Comment: @Michael I can't see anything like /var/lib/mysql in my root directory. i mean there's no such folder called var. Any way around?

Comment: Write it into `/tmp` which is likely to be there, and likely to be writable by the MySQL server user.

Comment: The funny thing that is happening is when i use path as /tmp/mydata.csv, the query gets executed , however, there's no such folder called tmp in my root directory! :s

Comment: @user1460822: Are you on a windows system? Pretty much every unix system on the planet has /tmp. On windows you might need to use `c:\temp` and create that dir

Comment: Also see related [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783313/how-can-i-get-around-mysql-errcode-13-with-select-into-outfile)

Comment: I believe the default behaviour is that it is written to the directory of the selected database, i.e. within the MySQL data directory (e.g. /var/lib/mysql/mydatabase).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

MySQL may be writing the file into its own data directory, like `/var/lib/mysql/<databasename>` for example.  To specify the path, use a full path.

However, it must be a directory that is writable by the user account the MySQL server daemon is running under.  For that reason, I'll often use `/tmp`:

Specify the path you want to write to as in:

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mydata.csv'
```

And note that MySQL will write the file on the MySQL *server*, not on your client machine. Therefore remote connections will create output files on the remote server.  See also [SELECT INTO OUTFILE local ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867607/mysql-select-into-outfile-local) for more details and workarounds.

#### Systemd  & Linux

**A note about writing to `/tmp` on a Linux system running `systemd`**:

Some years after originally posting this, I found myself unable to locate a file written to `/tmp` via

```
...INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/outfile.csv'
```

on a MariaDB 5.5 server running Fedora Linux with `systemd`.  Instead of writing the file directly to `/tmp/outfile.csv` as specified, that directory and file were created beneath a systemd directory in `/tmp`:

```
/tmp/systemd-mariadb.service-XXXXXXX/tmp/outfile.csv
```

While the file `outfile.csv` itself and the `tmp/` subdirectory were both created world-writable, the systemd service directory itself has 700 permissions and is root-owned, requiring `sudo` access to retrieve the file within it.

Rather than specifying the absolute path in MariaDB as `/tmp/outfile.csv` and specifying it relatively as `outfile.csv`, the file was written as expected into MariaDB's data directory for the currently selected database.

Comment: The funny thing that is happening is when i use path as /tmp/mydata.csv, the query gets executed , however, there's no such folder called tmp in my root directory! :s

Comment: @user1460822 If this is shared hosting, it's possible you just wrote that file to the system's common /tmp directory (which you can't access). It will get cleaned out eventually by automated scripts.  You need to write the file into a location you _can_ access, whatever that may be in your root directory.  If your root is something like `/home/users/your_username/public_html`, use that.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, I tried to put the file in `/home/username/myfolder/`. But I got `Persmission denied` error message. I did `chmod 777 /home/username/myfolder` and it still. Is it because of `chmod` only affect directories (not files)?

Comment: Note that if your mysql server is remote it will put file in its filesystem, not where your scripts are, and you should use scp to get it.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi If you are trying to write it into your home directory, you would need to ensure that the MySQL daemon user can traverse into it, which means adding execute permissions on `/home/username` with `chmod o+x /home/username` .  Homedirs are usually inaccessible to all but the owning user by design, so if you want to do it this way, I would recommend add the execute permission, then write the file, then immediately revoke it `chmod o-x /home/username`.  777 on the destination directory should work as long as the parent dir has execute.

Comment: @Tertium Yes, that wasn't very explicit in this answer. I added a link to another answer which explains the local issue thoroughly with workarounds.

Comment: Yeah, I've spend some time searching files on vps1, while they were on vps2 :)

Comment: "And note that MySQL will write the file on the MySQL server, not on your client machine. " - That was my problem, too!

Comment: Would have given you another upvote if possible. A note about writing to /tmp on a Linux system running systemd was the solution for my problem.

Comment: "/tmp/wog" as "/tmp/systemd-private-8c6e018a2da84e548935c16c457c9bc2-mariadb.service-uBrn8f/tmp/wog" on FC33 MariaDB 15.1

Answer (score 19):

I suspect you are looking for the file on your client machine.

`SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE` writes the file on the server machine.

Comment: yep...  this is the exact problem I had when looking into this issue.  Even though you are running the command on MySQL workbench, the file is written out on the server. Once I figured that out, it was a simple thing to just scp the file to my local machine.

Comment: very valuable detail!

Answer (score 5):

Just for Example:

I have run below query in **MySQL Workbench** & I found my file in

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`table` INTO OUTFILE 'file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

> **D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\db\file.csv**

You can use below example to set your file path:

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`table` INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my INTO OUTFILE files, created with the following command

> `select name from users into outfile "name.csv"`

at the following location

> **C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data\name.csv**

This is probably the default location, as I've never changed anything.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone on OS X has this problem, `mysql` installed with homebrew has default output located at `/usr/local/var/mysql/database-name/`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an absoulte path but use something like `INTO OUTFILE  'output.csv'` or `INTO OUTFILE './output.csv'`, it will store the output file to the directory specified by `show variables like 'datadir';`.

Answer (score 0):

You find the file in `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\data`, but the name will be `UsersNamecarro.txt` if you gave following `select * from carro where id_cor<4 INTO OUTFILE 'C:\Users\Name\carro.txt';`

So just write `.....OUTFILE 'C:\carro.txt'` to get file called `carro.txt` in `data` folder

Answer (score 0):

+1 to @michael-berkowski *and* the answer *i needed* for windows was (as he stated)

> MariaDB's data directory

to be specific, mine was in the data folder for database named "mydatabase"

> C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\data\mydatabase