# Can't Find File Created By OUTFILE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to save contents of the table 'dbtable' into a csv file using OUTFILE method. It doesn't give me any error and I am unable to find the file either. I have tried without defining the path and using 'mydata.csv' only too. But same result. I am using wamp on Windows 10.

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dbtable INTO OUTFILE 'C:\mydata.csv' FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\"' TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484471/cant-find-the-file-created-by-outfile-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks @VirendraNagda already tried didn't help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with path. It is not taking absolute path 'C:\' instead when I used relative path it worked. Earlier it was saving in /bin/mysql/data/ folder when saved without any path but using ../../../www/ enabled me to bring it to my www folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dbtable INTO OUTFILE 'C:\mydata.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

The main differences are I removed "FIELDS ESCAPED BY" as "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY" should take care of that. I found very few examples where "FIELDS ESCAPED BY" worked.