# Why does MySQL Select into outfile generate access error?

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

My question may really be, why can't MySQL write to /tmp. The server version is : `Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution`

Here are the details: I have looked through some of the suggested posts that popped up when I wrote the title to this post. I have also looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867607/mysql-select-into-outfile-local) and Snow Crashe's answer. I've looked again at one of my own [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285864/how-can-i-correct-mysql-load-error/16286112#16286112) and then searched the MySQL documentation hoping to find an option like `INTO LOCAL OUTFILE`, but such an option appears not to exist.

When I issue the following sql query, I get an access denied error.

```
SELECT * 
INTO  OUTFILE '/tmp/feb_gic.txt'
FROM   gic_employees 
WHERE  bill_month='201502';
```

My user has all privileges to a MySQL database given through `grant`.

So, after reading all this, why can't MySQL write to /tmp? MySQL cannot write to /tmp even if my user is logged into mysql, let alone if `mysql -e` is used.

Comment: The server needs to have access to the directory.

Comment: Does /tmp/feb_gic.txt exist? What does the ownership/permissions look like? Will it work if you `touch /tmp/feb_gic.txt && chmod 777 /tmp/feb_gic.txt`

Comment: No, I'm writing it out for the first time, but I'll try your suggestion. I've never had trouble dumping stuff out to /tmp though. That's what it's for.

Comment: @andrunix doing that won't work. I understand why MySQL can't write to my user's directory. MySQL doesn't have privileges to that, but it should have privileges to /tmp.