# How should I resolve --secure-file-priv in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I am learning MySQL and tried using a `LOAD DATA` clause. When I used it as below:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "text.txt" INTO table mytable;
```

I got the following error:

> The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

How do I tackle this error?

I have checked [another question on the same error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951468/error-code-1290-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-secure-file-priv-option), but still can’t find a solution.

I am using MySQL 5.6

Comment: share path of your csv file

Comment: Of course, you get this error when trying to use `mysqldump --tab`, as if it wasn't hard enough to get your own data out of mysql.

Comment: in addition for vhu's answer, search below for wolfsshield's answer. you need to switch to '/' to make it work (i am using win10)

Comment: use LOCAL.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...`

Comment: @mpoletto "Error Code: 1148. The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"

Comment: @Rodrigo Thank you! You need to see docs in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv . Note the build or maintenance number, i.e., 5.6.34 or 5.6.33, to see which better fit to your case. There is the variable secure-priv, then I'm supposing that default installation has a requirement about LOCAL, if not to use LOCAL explicitily, maybe setting directory in my.ini or my.cnf.

Answer (score 671, accepted):

It's working as intended. Your MySQL server has been started with [--secure-file-priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_secure-file-priv) option which limits from which directories you can load files using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` to see the directory that has been configured.

You have two options:

1. Move your file to the directory specified by `secure-file-priv`.
2. Disable `secure-file-priv`. This must be removed from startup and cannot be modified dynamically. To do this check your MySQL start up parameters (depending on platform) and my.ini.

Comment: Are you running MySQL on Linux or Windows? This option is either in the startup parameters or my.ini.

Comment: I am using on windows , I cant find a my.ini but found my-default.ini

Comment: By default my.ini can be found from "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6" when running MySQL 5.6 on W2012 server. You may also want to check the service startup parameters (e.g.  --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini) as they may also list `--secure-file-priv` itself.

Comment: instead of my.ini there is a my-default.ini at that location

Comment: Does the service startup parameters list `--defaults-file`?

Comment: @vhu, how can I change the service startup parameters? (since I don't seem to be able to edit the my.ini in ProgramData directory)

Comment: @Mohitbhasi, my-default.ini should be in the "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6" folder. The location vhu was referring to is "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6". Just in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: To answer the question I asked in last comment, install the service with this command:

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini"`

Comment: Sadly even inside the returned directory the same error occurs :(

Comment: I had this issue with a script which was trying to export to file.  I suspect it was introduced by an update/upgrade at some point down the line, with this setting being configured by default whereas previously it was not.  Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Value: NULL. FML.

Comment: For mysql 5.7.19 on Mac, I finally referenced this article for the solve: http://geodatawrangler.lazym8.com/blog/2017/02/16/secure-file-priv Do `mysql --help | more` to find where the my.cnf that mysql is referencing is.

Comment: Note that if using "select .. into outfile" you must specify the full path and the full path must match the results of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

Comment: "check the parameters" and "check my.ini" is not a very good answer

Comment: for a non-root user I simply had access denied, rather than "running with the --secure-file-priv option" which showed up when I tried under root. The fix being that as TheSatinKnight says, the path prefix matching the variable "secure_file_priv" must also be in place.

Comment: [how to disable the secure-file-priv in my.ini](https://superuser.com/questions/1088512/how-to-disable-secure-file-priv-mysql-ubuntu)

Comment: I am using a `LOAD DATA INFILE 'full_path\myfile.txt' ...` query, and it still gives the same error, even though `full_path\ ` *exactly* matches the string which is the value of `secure_file_priv`. The question remains: **"How do I tackle this error?"** The second answer below (by Staza) answers it.

Comment: I know this probably is answered somewhere but dear Lord I had to hunt down what to do with `MySql v8`. I had to manually find my `my.ini` file and add `secure-file-priv = ""`, otherwise I kept getting the same error no matter what I typed in there in the GUI.

Comment: @anddero It is a bit late for that but I had a similar issue - try use forward `/` slash in path instead of backslash `\ `

Comment: Also, note the spelling of the option to change in the config file: secure-file-priv  **and not** secure_file_priv.

Comment: A third option!! Set your secure-file-priv as `'C:\'` or `'path/to/your/user'`...as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40247853/mysql-set-secure-file-priv-to-multiple-directories) because all folders below are allowed

Comment: I moved my file to the directory indicated by "secure-file-priv" and I still get the same error. My SQL query looks like this: "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "csvData.csv""

Answer (score 306):

I solved it using the `LOCAL` option in the command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "text.txt" INTO TABLE mytable;
```

You can find more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the
> client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full
> path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path
> name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the
> client program was started.

Comment: This worked for me and none other. I tried: 1. to upload my txt file in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads`, 2. disabling `secure_file_priv` in `my.ini` and restarting mysql 3. This one!
Thanks :)

Comment: This worked for me too. I was going to move the files to the secure-fle-priv directory but I didn't have to because this worked perfectly.

Comment: I got this error message for MariaDB: "ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version". The exact version: "mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.22-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.2"

Comment: I got "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version" for mysql version 5.7.19.

Comment: Worked beautifully on MySQL 5.7.17 running on Windows. Thank you!

Comment: Actually this answer is the correct one and deserves to be the accepted answer!

Comment: Worked for me as well (after I changed backslashes to forward slashes in the connection string). Thank you!

Comment: @AlisonS Try adding the `--local-infile` flag when running `mysql`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762239/mysql-enable-load-data-local-infile

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: `The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version` from MySQL 8.0

Comment: Worked for me. Unsure why adding the local-keyword changed security measures.

Comment: @bitfishxyz, you probably already solved this, but I just had the same issue and found this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html    `sudo mysqlimport --local db_name import_file`

Comment: Note there are some serious security issues if you're too loose with using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local.html (mustafa's answer is probably safer)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. A user may want to import data but may not have privs to access /var/lib/mysql-files.

Comment: Uh, this is only the "correct" answer for those who have the file locally. It doesn't help for those working on remote systems where the file to be loaded is on the same system as the server and NOT on the local system at all.

Comment: Error Code: 3948. Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

Answer (score 148):

On Ubuntu 14 and Mysql 5.5.53 this setting seems to be enabled by default. To disable it you need to add `secure-file-priv = ""` to your my.cnf file under the mysqld config group. eg:-

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Same version of Ubuntu and MySQL

Comment: +1 Worked for me. If you are using Ubuntu, don't forget restart mysql service: sudo service mysql restart

Comment: This is what works if you need it to point to a location that you select per statement where applicable. This works with MySQL 5.7 on Windows Server just as you explained. If you simply comment out the line like `# secure-file-priv = ~` then it still has the error since the value shows as `NULL` doing it this way resolves the problem when you want to pick which directories you can export to on the server, etc.

Comment: Worked for me with MySQL 5.7 on Windows, whereas the other solutions did not.

Comment: NB: if doing this in Docker you must restart the Docker container.

Comment: Ok for MySQL 5.5 on Windows too.

Comment: Be Careful when doing that, if a hacker gains access to your database in any way he will be able to hack the whole system if you disabled secure-file-priv, this is a really bad practice.

Comment: Vagrant also needs to be restarted, and yes, Shamaseen is correct, it is bad practice, but when working locally, its fine for development

Comment: This worked for me when adding `local_infile=1` as well.

Answer (score 68):

@vhu I did the `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` and it returned `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\` so when I plugged that in, it still didn't work.

When I went to the `my.ini` file directly I discovered that the path is formatted a bit differently:

```
C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads
```

Then when I ran it with that, it worked. The only difference was the direction of the slashes.

Comment: Yes yes yes...why is this answer so far below. i struggled for long time and then got it. i came back to add this as the answer but it is so far down that i didn't see it before i wasted my time.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes.

Comment: Awesome this was the exact issue on MySql 8.0

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me combining the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61675576/12097072) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737616/12097072)

Answer (score 47):

I'm working on MySQL5.7.11 on Debian, the command that worked for me to see the directory is:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv;
```

Comment: With `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` I get `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'performance_schema.session_variables' doesn't exist` which is also thrown in other circumstances and I will have to eventually deal with. The `SELECT @@global.secure_file_priv;` command though produced the expected result.

Comment: This worked for me -- Ubuntu Mysql 5.7.21: changed the output file to directory  /var/lib/mysql-files/output.txt

Comment: How you edit it then? I tried to edit it in /etc/mysql/my.cnf and it seems to have no effect - it stays NULL

Answer (score 38):

Here is what worked for me in Windows 7 to disable `secure-file-priv` (Option #2 from [vhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737616/209139)):

1. Stop the MySQL server service by going into `services.msc`.
2. Go to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` (`ProgramData` was a hidden folder in my case).
3. Open the `my.ini` file in Notepad.
4. Search for 'secure-file-priv'.
5. Comment the line out by adding '#' at the start of the line. For MySQL Server 5.7.16 and above, commenting won't work.  You have to set it to an empty string like this one - `secure-file-priv=""`
6. Save the file.
7. Start the MySQL server service by going into `services.msc`.

Comment: As of MySQL Server 5.7.16, commenting out the line will not work, because then it will revert to the default, which disables import and export operations. You now need to set it to an empty string if you want to allow these operations from any directory.

Comment: Ramnath, please, edit your answer with @dbc detail for 5.7.x version. Thanks.

Comment: Adding an empty string works for me; please change the answer to add an empty string like secure-file-priv=""

Comment: For Windows make sure to use forward slashes

Answer (score 28):

If the file is local to your machine use the **LOCAL** in your command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "text.txt" INTO table mytable;
```

Answer (score 21):

The thing that worked for me:

1. Put your file inside of the folder specified in `secure-file-priv`.

   To find that type:

   ```
   mysql> show variables like "secure_file_priv";
   ```
2. Check if you have `local_infile = 1`.

   Do that typing:

   ```
   mysql> show variables like "local_infile";
   ```

   If you get:

   ```
   +---------------+-------+
   | Variable_name | Value |
   +---------------+-------+
   | local_infile  | OFF   |
   +---------------+-------+
   ```

   Then set it to one typing:

   ```
   mysql> set global local_infile = 1;
   ```
3. Specify the full path for your file. In my case:

   ```
   mysql> load data infile "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/file.txt" into table test;
   ```

Answer (score 18):

This thread has been viewed 570k times at the time of this post. Honestly when did MySQL become our over protective unreasonable mom? What a time consuming attempt at security - which really only serves to shackle us!

After many searches and many attempts everything failed.
My solution:

What worked for me was:

1. Import the `.csv` file via PhpMyAdmin import on older box (if large do at cmd line)
2. Generate a `.sql` file.
3. Download `.sql` file.
4. Import `.sql` file via MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 14):

For mysql 8.0 version you can do this:

```
mysql.server stop
mysql.server start --secure-file-priv=''
```

It worked for me on Mac High Sierra.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in macOS 11.3 beta. MySQL 5.7

Comment: Didn't work in macOS 10.5.5 Catalina either; It set the flag to null, but didn't prevent the error.

Comment: Worked for me in MaOS 10.15.7 Catalina / MySQL 8.0.22 Homebrew.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with 'secure-file-priv'. Commenting in the .ini file didn't work and neither did moving file in directory specified by 'secure-file-priv'.

Finally, as dbc suggested, making 'secure-file-priv' equal to an empty string worked. So if anyone is stuck after trying answers above, hopefully doing this will help.

Answer (score 7):

If you're running on Ubuntu, you may also need to configure Apparmor to allow MySQL to write to your folder, e.g. here's my configuration:

Add this line to file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld :

```
/var/lib/mysql-files/* rw
```

Then add these 2 config lines to /etc/mysql/my.cnf sections:

```
[client]
loose-local-infile = 1

[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Here's my SQL:

```
select id from blahs into outfile '/var/lib/mysql-files/blahs';
```

It worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: Yes putting outfile path with "/var/lib/mysql-files/filename.csv" worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had all sorts of problems with this. I was changing my.cnf and all sorts of crazy things that other versions of this problem tried to show.

What worked for me:

The error I was getting

`The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`

I was able to fix it by opening /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server and changing the following line:

```
$bindir/mysqld_safe --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" -- $other_args >/dev/null &
  wait_for_pid created "$!" "$mysqld_pid_file_path"; return_value=$?
```

to

```
$bindir/mysqld_safe --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" --secure-file-priv="" $other_args >/dev/null &
  wait_for_pid created "$!" "$mysqld_pid_file_path"; return_value=$?
```

Answer (score 5):

I created a NodeJS import script if you are running nodeJS and you data is in the following form (double quote + comma and \n new line)

```
INSERT INTO <your_table> VALUEs( **CSV LINE **)
```

This one is configured to run on http://localhost:5000/import.

I goes *line by line* and creates query string

```
"city","city_ascii","lat","lng","country","iso2","iso3","id"
"Tokyo","Tokyo","35.6850","139.7514","Japan","JP","JPN","1392685764",
...
```

server.js

```js
const express = require('express'),
   cors = require('cors'),
   bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
   cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
   session = require('express-session'),
   app = express(),
   port = process.env.PORT || 5000,
   pj = require('./config/config.json'),
   path = require('path');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());


app.use(
   bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: false,
   })
);

var Import = require('./routes/ImportRoutes.js');

app.use('/import', Import);
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   // set static folder
   app.use(express.static('client/build'));

   app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
   });
}

app.listen(port, function () {
   console.log('Server is running on port: ' + port);
});
```

ImportRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express'),
   cors = require('cors'),
   fs = require('fs-extra'),
   byline = require('byline'),
   db = require('../database/db'),
   importcsv = express.Router();

importcsv.use(cors());

importcsv.get('/csv', (req, res) => {

   function processFile() {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
         let first = true;
         var sql, sqls;
         var stream = byline(
            fs.createReadStream('../PATH/TO/YOUR!!!csv', {
               encoding: 'utf8',
            })
         );

         stream
            .on('data', function (line, err) {
               if (line !== undefined) {
                  sql = 'INSERT INTO <your_table> VALUES (' + line.toString() + ');';
                  if (first) console.log(sql);
                  first = false;
                  db.sequelize.query(sql);
               }
            })
            .on('finish', () => {
               resolve(sqls);
            });
      });
   }

   async function startStream() {
      console.log('started stream');
      const sqls = await processFile();
      res.end();
      console.log('ALL DONE');
   }

   startStream();
});

module.exports = importcsv;
```

db.js is the config file

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = {};
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
   config.global.db,
   config.global.user,
   config.global.password,
   {
      host: config.global.host,
      dialect: 'mysql',
      logging: console.log,
      freezeTableName: true,

      pool: {
         max: 5,
         min: 0,
         acquire: 30000,
         idle: 10000,
      },
   }
);

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**Disclaimer:**  This is not a perfect solution - I am only posting it for devs who are under a timeline and have lots of data to import and are encountering this ridiculous issue.  I lost a lot of time on this and I hope to spare another dev the same lost time.

Answer (score 4):

At macOS Catalina, I followed this steps to set `secure_file_priv`

**1.Stop MySQL service**

```
 sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop
```

**2.Restart MYSQL assigning --secure_file_priv system variables**

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --secure-file-priv=YOUR_FILE_DIRECTORY
```

Note: Adding empty value fix the issue for me, and MYSQL will export data to directory /usr/local/mysql/data/YOUR_DB_TABLE/EXPORT_FILE

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --secure-file-priv=
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me (had the additional problem of not being able to use LOCAL with my current MySQL version in the statement LOAD DATE INFILE ... )

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start --secure-file-priv='' --local-infile
```

The above works for that given path on my machine; you may have to adjust your path.

Then use:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

One important point is that you should have the CSV in the MySQL data folder. In my machine it is located at: /usr/local/mysql-8.0.18-macos10.14-x86_64/data

You can change the folder permission if needed to drop a CSV in the data folder.

Setup:
macOS Catalina version 10.15.5
MySQL version 8.0.18

Answer (score 3):

MySQL use this system variable to control where you can import you files

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv | NULL  |
+------------------+-------+
```

So problem is how to change system variables such as `secure_file_priv`.

1. shutdown `mysqld`
2. `sudo mysqld_safe --secure_file_priv=""`

now you may see like this:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv |       |
+------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

in **Linux** you have to edit my.cnf file in

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and change `26 line number` param like this :

```
secure-file-priv= <your data path directory like /home/user/data>
```

then restart your MySQL and try again.

in **docker**
you have to mount your my.cnf file with my.cnf file in your container with this command in docker-compose or add manually :

```
volumes:
  - ./persistent:/var/lib/mysql
  - ./conf/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

next change /conf/my.cnf in your host and config **secure-file-priv param** like the upper approach, in addition, you have to mount your data in mysql container and set that path for **secure-file-priv param** and restart your services and finally, you can load your data.

you can check your config with this command :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

Answer (score 3):

I added the `LOCAL` to the command, but it made another problem:

```
Loading local data is disabled - this must be enabled on both the client and server sides
```

For solving this I simply followed three steps in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993844/error-loading-local-data-is-disabled-this-must-be-enabled-on-both-the-client)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the explanation about `secure_file_priv`:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv

And here is the explanation of `LOAD DATA`:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

In my case, MySQL from the official Docker image is in use, so I needed to figure out how to set `secure_file_priv`.

- To understand better what is `secure_file_priv` I read the about it in the link above;
- And read what MySQL' DockerHub had to say, https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

To know (docker) *mysql* defaults:

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm mysql --verbose --help
Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}          Value (after reading options)
----------------------------------------- -----------------------------
...
local-infile                              FALSE
...
secure-file-priv                          NULL
...
```

In fact, (inside the container,) the config file says:

```
root@a2b1e0c46541:/# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
#
# (...license...)
#
# The MySQL  Server configuration file.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL

# Custom config should go here
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Using the official image (as explained in the README):

```sh
$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret -d mysql \
         --secure_file_priv=/data
```

> If you want to allow `LOCAL INFILE` load, define also the option `local_infile=TRUE`.

Now you should be able to `LOAD DATA INFILE '/data/data.csv' INTO TABLE some_table`.

**NOTE**: In the same task -- once the "INFILE" thing was solved (above) -- I had issues with *empty* values in my CSV data, to which the answer (and question) was very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968530/687896 .

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on windows 10. "--secure-file-priv in MySQL" To solve this I did the following.

1. In windows search (bottom left) I typed "powershell".
2. Right clicked on powershell and ran as admin.
3. Navigated to the server bin file. (C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin);
4. Typed ./mysqld
5. Hit "enter"

The server started up as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Without changing any of the configuration files..

1. look for the value of `secure_file_priv` using the command posted by @vhu: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"`.
2. define the full path for your query such as: `select * from table into outfile 'secure_file_priv_PATH/OUTPUT-FILE' ... rest of your query`

this worked for my in mysql-shell on ubuntu 18.04 LTS mysql 5.7.29

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS Mojave running MySQL 5.6.23 I had this problem with *writing* files, but not *loading* them. (Not seen with previous versions of Mac OS). As most of the answers to this question have been for other systems, I thought I would post the my.cnf file that cured this (and a socket problems too) in case it is of help to other Mac users. This is  **/etc/my.cnf**

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
secure-file-priv = ""
skip-external-locking
```

(The internationalization is irrelevant to the question.)

Nothing else required. Just turn the MySQL server off and then on again in Preferences (we are talking Mac) for this to take.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue here, ERRORCODE 2. Yes most of the answers do make sense, however I tried the simplest method :

I used double slashes in the path for the file.

my sample path with the entire query >> TRY IT and please let everyone know if it worked for you.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "E:\Irfan One Drive\OneDrive - Qtech\Documents\Suppliers\HB\Extended\HotelTransferZone.csv"
INTO TABLE `temp_hb_transfer`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 20.04:
Run the following command to locate my.cnf in system:

```
commandlocate my.cnf
```

Now: Edit this file

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add the following line in the end:

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

Now you can import files, This error will be removed.
Or you can use Mysql work bench file to import:
link: https://blog.skyvia.com/how-to-import-csv-file-into-mysql-table-in-4-different-ways/