# MySQL how to use 'load_file()' for all paths? Not just Server Host folder

Tags: mysql

**Goal**

My goal is to insert `BLOB` data into MySQL from various paths - **NOT** just MySQL server host folder.

**Where I am at now**

I am able to write a query using `load_file()` function using this path only - `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads`

**Problem**

When using any other paths such as the *\Desktop* - MySQL values show as *NULL*.

As the documentation states [*"To use this function, the file must be located on the server host."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file)

**Question**

How can I `GRANT` or enable privilege to use `load_file()` for any path?

**Root Grant Privileges**

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO "root"@"%" WITH GRANT OPTION
```

**EDIT:**

Got something out of here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42410342/12485722

*"If you need to change the path, you must do it in the my.ini file:"*

*" Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv="V:/NEW/PATH/TO/MySQL Server/Files" "*

How can I add multiple paths in the `.ini` file?

Comment: If you have the files in same drive you could use only the drive letter like `secure-file-priv =  "C:/"` or if more then add multiple lines mentioning the drive letter. This should be added in your config file.

Comment: sorry i can't get you