# Loading data from a csv with mysql, file not found error

Tags: mysql

For the past 2 days, I have been trying to load data from a CSV file into a mySQL database. At first, I encountered the secure file priv error, which didn't go away when I changed my file location, or when I commented out the relevant line in "my.ini". When I eventually resolved that by changing its value to an empty string, I discovered that I still couldn't load the file as I was getting `OS errno2 no such file or directory`.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/Users/ehize/Downloads/not414.csv" 
INTO TABLE birthrate 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I don't know if this makes any difference, but I'm hosting this mysql server on my system. I have also tried the `LOAD DATA LOCAL`, but it makes no difference as \I get  the same file not found error. Honestly at my wits end here. Everyone online just talks about changing backslashes to front-slashes or double back-slashes, none of which make any difference. Please help of any form would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure the '--secure-file-priv' option is turned off, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596163/disable-secure-priv-for-data-loading-on-mysql

Comment: Did you also check if the file is really at that location, using: `\system dir "C:\Users\ehize\Downloads\not414.csv"` ?

Comment: In the end, I think the issue was with my table column data types

Comment: No, this would lead to other error messages, and not to the error you where reporting ... ("OS errno2 no such file or directory")

Comment: So what would lead to that error?

Comment: In order to get an answer which will help you you need to make the question in a [mre]. Post a minimal input file, which will lead to the error reported.