# How to execute this LOAD XML INFILE SQL query?

Tags: mysql, xml

I already have a table in place which I'm trying to populate using the data from an external XML file. I'm using the `LOAD XML INFILE` function for it, using the query below. However I'm getting a `#1290 - The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement` and the query is unable to execute. Can anybody please enlighten me as to what needs to be done so that I can execute it?

Here's the query for reference.

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'C:\\Users\Shubham\Desktop\Part_Info.xml' 
INTO TABLE dbtest.part_no
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>';
```

Comment: Have a look at [MySQL : How to tackle --secure-file-priv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/mysql-how-to-tackle-secure-file-priv)

Comment: @MikeT Thank you for the reference link you shared. I'm afraid I had already seen it and some other questions like this. I tried the workaround he suggests (of moving the file to the location prompted by `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`) but it did't work and I'm still stuck with the same error as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I found the answer myself.

For the specifics, I'm working on Windows and installed MySQL in-part with the general WAMP installation.

I tried the solution that @MikeT (in the comments above) suggested. The workaround mentioned was

- To move the file you want to import to the directory specified by `secure-file-priv` brought by the SQL query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

However the error (for me atleast) still persisted. But the error was resolved (again, for me atleast) by using forward-slashes instead of backslashes using the file path, as indicated by the following SQL query

```
LOAD XML INFILE 'D://Secondary/wamp64/tmp/Part_Info.xml'
INTO TABLE dbtest.part_no
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<row>'
```

Hope it helps.