# Using LOAD DATA INFILE in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to read data from a text file and input them into a database. I found this example in the SQL docs that fits my case:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE table2 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

So I am trying to write this in Java. So far I have this:

```
String insertTableSQL = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Work/Desktop/test/masterDict'"
                    + "INTO TABLE masterdict" + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'" 
                    ;
```

But this gives me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TERMINATED BY ','' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss some blanks:

```
String insertTableSQL = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Work/Desktop/test/masterDict '"
                    + " INTO TABLE masterdict" + " FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'" 
                    ;
```

Because you querystring will result in:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Work/Desktop/test/masterDict'INTO TABLE masterdictFIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
```

Comment: Jens thank you for your answer :) it works i have no syntax errors now, but instead it gives me this "The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement" do you have any idea what this is?

Comment: @SteveEmman Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/mysql-how-to-tackle-secure-file-priv

Comment: Thank you! Should i edit my question to include this link too? I think a lot of beginners might run to both problems as well.

Comment: I would upvote your answer as well but unfortunately i must have at least 15 reputation