# MySQL set secure-file-priv to multiple directories

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to allow MySQL to load data from multiple directories without setting `secure-file-priv=''`?

E.g., something like:

```
secure-file-priv="path/to/dir1","path/to/dir2"
```

From reading the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv), it isn't clear if multiple directories are allowed, and if so, how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no. You can only set a single location for `secure-file-priv`.

That said, every *sub-directory* of the configuration can be written to.

If you wanted to write anywhere on the system then you would configure it like this:

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv="/"
```

It's important to note that any file created by `into outfile` is [writable by all users](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

Comment: My files are going to the secure_file_priv location just fine when I use into outfile, but when I try to outfile to 2 subfolders in that directory it gives me a "permission denied" message. I figured it would just work since ultimately the files are still being output to within the secure_file_priv directory. Do I need to enable something else for it to work?

Comment: On MySQL 5.7.x I am also running into the fact that the location, if set, requires the file to be present directly in it. Targeting any subdirectories (or soft/hard links) within that location will all trigger the `cannot execute` error.