# Where to find where mysql startup variables are set?

Tags: mysql, configuration

I am encountering a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql), in that I cannot export to a file, but is not a duplicate as I am not asking how to fix that problem, but to find where the variables are set.

When I run 'mysqld --verbose --help', secure-file-priv is ONLY set to null. And it does read:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

BUT this does not seem to be the actual config, but the default. I installed with homebrew.

I tried many of the provided solutions, but that variable just seems to not change after I make a change and then stop, start servers.

What I have tried:

1. adding 'secure-file-priv = ""'

   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/federated/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_memcache/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_ddl/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_binlog/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_big/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndbcluster/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_team/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_rpl/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/rpl_ndb/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/rpl/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/rpl/extension/bhs/my.cnf
   /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf
2. I have set that same item to an actual location. Still shows as NULL.
3. I have edited mysqld.cnf to have the same settings.
4. I have edited com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist to have that setting (I am on Mac El Capitain)

I think my next step is to uninstall and reinstall, but would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was getting

`The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`

I was able to fix it by opening /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server and changing the following line:

```
$bindir/mysqld_safe --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" -- $other_args >/dev/null &
  wait_for_pid created "$!" "$mysqld_pid_file_path"; return_value=$?
```

to

```
$bindir/mysqld_safe --datadir="$datadir" --pid-file="$mysqld_pid_file_path" --secure-file-priv="" $other_args >/dev/null &
  wait_for_pid created "$!" "$mysqld_pid_file_path"; return_value=$?
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you install MySQL via MAMP, the config file is simply the local dot file here:**

```
~/.my.cnf
```

**To enable file read/write for MySQL installed via MAMP (on Mac):**

1. open "MAMP" use spotlight
2. click "Stop Servers"
3. edit ~/.my.cnf (using vi or your favorite editor) and the following lines:

   $ vi ~/.my.cnf

> ```
> [mysqld_safe]
> [mysqld]
> secure_file_priv="/Users/russian_spy/"
> ```

4. click "Start Servers" (in MAMP window)

**Now check if it works:**

a. start mysql (default MAMP user is root, password is also root)

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

b. in mysql look at the white-listed paths

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /Users/russian_spy/          |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

c. Finally, test by exporting a table `train` into a CSV file

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM train INTO OUTFILE '/Users/russian_spy/test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
Query OK, 992931 rows affected (1.65 sec)

mysql>
```