# SQL Create Queries And Redirect To File

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've written a query and have filtered out the E.G "Salaries over $120,000."

I want to redirect the answer to a .csv file, however Im experiencing issues.

Ive read online that : To redirect the output of your queries to a file, append the following

clause to your queries:

```
INTO OUTFILE <filename> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

However: when I append this to my query...

```
SELECT from_date FROM dept_emp_latest_date WHERE from_date < '2002-08-01' and from_date > '2002-07-01' INTO OUTFILE new_hires.csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I just get a syntax error.

The query below works fine. But I need help to redirect it to my file... new_hires.csv.

```
SELECT from_date FROM dept_emp_latest_date WHERE from_date < '2002-08-01' and from_date > '2002-07-01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to put `new_hires.csv` inside single quotes (`'new_hires.csv'`).

Also, I think the order of your statements needs to put the `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses at the end. Give this a try:

```
SELECT from_date INTO OUTFILE 'new_hires.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM dept_emp_latest_date
WHERE from_date < '2002-08-01' AND from_date > '2002-07-01';
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the syntax error! Thank you very much!

Comment: Im now prompted with the error: ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: [Take a look at this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql). It explain why the error pops up for a similar problem and how to resolve it.

Comment: Thank you @UnseenSpecter