# I am trying to store data of mysql db into csv file using query but it returns error msg.

Tags: mysql

SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'dataset.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '""' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM reviews.opinions;

ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: A little search with your error message quickly gets you there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql

Comment: this reference is for loading text file data into database table. But i am trying to write table data into csv file..

Comment: The answer to your question is in the accepted answer of the reference.