# How to export mysql table data to a file

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to export data from a table to excel file.

I am using the select ... INTO ... file method to do so. I am getting the error

```
Error Code: 1290 The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

The output of below query is NULL.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

In the post below, staza resolved the issue by adding LOCAL> But their issue was while working with importing csv to MySQL while mine is exporting from MySQL to csv. Is there any "LOCAL" equivalent for the export issue?

[How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are running MySQL -secure-file-priv you can read and write files only from and to the upload directory.

Under Windows this typically is somewhere under

```
C:\programdata\
```

Comment: I am on mac. Would you know the equivalent path. Even then, if the value is set to NULL, would it let you download to that path?