# How to Disable "secure-file-priv" on Windows?

Tags: mysql, import-from-excel

I am trying to import data from csv to mysql table using load data infile.
Have moved the csv file to the directory (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\1JulySales.csv).

And have executed the command
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\1Julysales.csv' into table Sales;

and error shows up.
The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Also referred to this problem on this thread.
[How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Please help.
Thanks.
Santosh.

Comment: find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql

Comment: What is the exact error message? You might just need to escape the backslash character. (lol I don't know how to escape this character in this comment :D)