# Can't write MySQL output to local file

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I can not write my query result to local file. I am sure my query produces output. I can view it. I use MySQL workbench on Ubuntu 18.04. After I added this line to write the output to a file:

```
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/myproject/out_files/mydata.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

I looked int previous posts. I made sure that the `/var/lib/mysql-files` is the specified path for writing. This is the output I get:
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv;

```
+---------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /var/lib/mysql-files/     |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `secure_file_priv` must name the directory you output into exactly. You can't output into subdirectories.

Here's a demo I just did using MySQL 5.6 on my laptop:

```
mysql> select @@global.secure_file_priv;
+---------------------------+
| @@global.secure_file_priv |
+---------------------------+
| /tmp/                     |
+---------------------------+

mysql> select 123 into outfile '/tmp/foo';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Check that the data was written out:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo
123
```

Then try a subdirectory:

```
mysql> select 456 into outfile '/tmp/a/b/text';
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Even if I `mkdir -p /tmp/a/b` to make sure the subdirectory exists before I try this, it still fails.