# Cannot import txt file on MySQL Server 8.0, because of secure_file_priv

Tags: mysql, import, upload

I have followed this reply, but still does not work...

[How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32737616/4275509)

I run:
    LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\Parts_with_eClass_Code.txt' INTO TABLE partnumbersclassified;

I get the following:

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I have added the file in the standard Uploads folder here:

```
'secure_file_priv', 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\'
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: Check if you have local_infile = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your file path and replace "\" to "/". I solved my problem after replacing that...

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Parts_with_eClass_Code.txt' INTO TABLE partnumbersclassified.

I wished they could given another error code for this type of errors...