# MySQL Workbench Error 1290 on Mac Os Catalina Version 10.15.2 when trying to load in csv-file into a table on my database

Tags: mysql, database, csv, mysql-workbench, macos-catalina

I am creating a database on MySQL workbench and I try to load a csv-file into a table that I have created in one of my schemas.
When I try to load in a csv-file into my table on mysql workbench with the following command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/user_name/Desktop/A1 Aufgabe/Bestand_YE2007.csv'
INTO TABLE bestand2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

it shows:

```
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement    0.0027 sec
```

I think I just need to change the variable `secure_file_priv` to `empty`,
but I can't find a

> my.ini

file or a

> my.cnf

file on my Mac anywhereto configure this. 
Is there a file like that or do I need to create one somehow?

Comment: please check if this heps https://stackoverflow.com/a/40630313/5193536

Comment: Try adding `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.....`