# How to solve MySql "Cannot execute this command" error?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

When I try to run this command

```
select name, address, age into outfile 'user.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' from StudentTable;"
```

I got an error from MySql:

> "ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"

Comment: Refer the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql) and it can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT @@secure_file_priv;
```

To see what Folder is secure.

If it returns f.e

> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\

Use

```
select name, address, age into outfile 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\user.csv' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
from StudentTable;
```

the Backslashes must be **doubled**

To disable change in he my.ini file

```
[mysqld]
secure-file-priv = ""
```

But that is insecure, because you can save anywhere you have write rights, bit alsoo there mus specify the folder where you want to write it for example

```
c:\\temp\\user.csv
```