# how to load the csv file to docker mysql

Tags: mysql, docker

I have followed some of the stackoverflow thread to come this far upto loading an image and getting the csv file into the docker container. Below are the steps followed:

1. Loaded the mysql lite into docker
2. Executed docker and set the default root password and went inside mysql to create databases and empty schema table
3. copied the csv file to the docker container docker cp C:\<> <>:filename.csv
4. when I tried to load this csv to the table, it is throwing me error `LOAD DATA INFILE filename.csv into TABLE tablename COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',';`

The error message is

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Thank you in advance Please assist

Comment: The duplicate question can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql

Comment: or yo ucould use [LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html) which has a different set of security entanglement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Comment: just an idea, use docker volume to load file inside docker https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/