# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE issue

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a .csv file into my table named ImportMaia, and I have used the following code to do so:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\esomm\Documents\Maia.xlsx' INTO TABLE MaiaImport
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

I was given the following error:

*"The MySQL server is running with --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"*

I tried to use `SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;`, but that didn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well `xlsx` is not a `CSV` so that also could cause issues. Why not move the file to the correct dir?

Comment: You're definitely right, I changed that but still no luck.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I tackle --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-tackle-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Comment: I would use the first option, move the file to the `secure-file-priv` locatin

Answer (score 0):

The command must be, to disable it

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile= "OFF";
```

But i doubt that it will tun even then, Look at the file in an hex editor and see if the codes match with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: It said the local_infile can't be set to that value

Comment: Sorry it didn't copy the value