# The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I got the error `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`.
How to disable this on a MacOS software.

I tired all the steps mentioned in this tutorial, but it didn't work - https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-solve-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-secure-file-priv-error/.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What statement ?  Please post your schema and your query

Comment: Have a look at [How should I resolve --secure-file-priv in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-resolve-secure-file-priv-in-mysql)

Comment: I have tried `load data infile` and when I executed this query, I got the `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement`. I tried all the steps mentioned in the link provided by you, but still I got the same error. I tried to import the table directly from MySQL Workbench, it was working for me.