# How do I change the secure-file-priv variable for MySQL on Mac?

Tags: mysql, macos

Been trying to solve this problem for hours now and nothing seems to be working. I am trying to set up MySQL to be able to upload csv files automatically in code like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/aubrey/Documents/dbproject/dates_table.csv' 
INTO TABLE dates 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

This gives me the error:
**Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement**

I read up on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-resolve-secure-file-priv-in-mysql) and [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv) about the `secure-file-priv` options. The result of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` is `NULL`. So I need to change that to be the directory I want in the `my.cnf` file. Cool.

I did that.
[image: /etc/my.cnf file]

And after restarting the server, that shows up in the workbench Options File (Administration tab, under Instances)
[image: Options file shows directory path]

But when I run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` again, I still get `NULL`
[image: still null]

I've tried both `secure-file-priv` and `secure_file_priv`, both show up in the options correctly but give a null in SHOW VARIABLES.

What am I doing wrong?

Running Ventura 13.1, MySQL 8.0.32ARM64

Comment: Did you restart the mysql service after changing the value in the my.cnf file? Also check your MySQL error log. There will be a warning if the directory is insecure. For example, if it is accessible to all users, it won't be allowed.

Comment: @BillKarwin I did restart the servers after changing the file.
This might be a problem, when I look for the error logs I get this: "Error creating log reader: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err'
"...

Comment: That's probably because the file is not readable by your non-privileged user. Try reading it with `sudo`.

Comment: Only two [Warning] are:
[Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
[Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it (also Mac ARM64 with MySQL 8.0.32 installed form homebrew), and it works for me.

Comment: Just tried uninstalling, then installing with Homebrew and I get the same thing. my.cnf says the directory, the options file has the same directory, but show variables still null. AARGHUJNEFWBIWNDMJK

Comment: My only other suggestion is that you're editing the wrong my.cnf file. It can be quite difficult to figure out which my.cnf file is the one in use on a Mac.

Comment: That could be, but I just don't know why the Options File would pick up the changes in the my.cnf file but the DB doesn't. Thanks for your efforts though!