# Mysql - log file creation while exeuting scripts

Tags: mysql, my.ini

Below is query to make a log file creation in the directory D:\ drive

/* Log details with date and time of execution start */
SELECT CONCAT('Execution started at: ', NOW()) AS log_details INTO OUTFILE 'D:/logfile.log' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Below is the error while exeucting the above query`your text`

Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement 0.000 sec

i updated below details in my.ini and restart service of mysql

[mysqld]
secure-file-priv=d:/

please post your answer if you have already gone through the steps which i performed and went through this type of error.

thank you all.

i mentioned the my try and expection is to resolve mean i should be able to create log file using mysql workbench enviroment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32737478/how-should-i-resolve-secure-file-priv-in-mysql?rq=2