How to pipe to "null object" in bash?
I have the following:
if [[ "${outfile}" == '/dev/stdout' ]]; then
  "${mysql_cmd[@]}" <"${infile}" >"${outfile}"
else
  "${mysql_cmd[@]}" <"${infile}" |
    sed -e 's|[[:<:]]NULL[[:>:]]|\\N|g' >"${outfile}"
fi

The sed is meant to convert NULL to \N so that the output can be used with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
I'd like to make it into a one-liner similar to:
"${mysql_cmd[@]}" <"${infile}" | "${transformer_cmd[@]}" >"${outfile}"

When transformer_cmd is a "null object" (ie not the sed command), mysql must continue to be interactive (such that a mysql shell is opened in which one can enter in SQL statements). I've tried cat as transformer_cmd and that failed this requirement.
Is this possible? If so, how?
I'd rather avoid doing something like "${mysql_cmd[@]}" <"${infile}" "${transformer_cmd}" >"${outfile}" such that transformer_cmd includes the | but will do so if there's no other way.
ADDENDUM: transformer_cmd including the | doesn't work since for some reason ${transformer_cmd} (without surrounding double quotes) is still being interpreted as an argument to mysql.

Unquoted | is part of the syntax of a shell pipeline, not an argument to the first command. (It's closer to think of both commands as "arguments" to | instead.)

As far as I know, mysql is only interactive if and only if its standard input is a terminal.

What does "interactive" mean here, like user-interactive? Most programs that read standard input don't run interactively if you provide anything on standard input.

>/dev/stdout makes little sense. /dev/stdout is just a synonym for stdout, which is where output goes by default.

if you're trying to get the usual table formatting of output, you can force that with the --table option.

You could use the pager command within the MySQL client. You don't have to set it to more or less as pagers, you could use any filtering command. I often use it for grep.

Not the problem you're asking about but having a variable named STDOUT that sometimes is not stdout seems like a bad idea. Maybe name it OUTFD or similar (but also stop using all upper case variable names for non-exported variables of course).

@tjm3772, "interactive" means that a mysql shell is opened in which one can type in SQL statements

@Barmar, ${STDOUT} may evaluate to a filename depending on parameters to the script

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406521/133219 may help you along with | cat.

@BillKarwin, --pager is a great idea. Unfortunately, it's documented to work only in interactive mode and sed isn't included in the valid commands

@Barmar, I'm trying to output a file that can be used with INFILE (which interprets \N as NULL). --table still outputs NULL which needs to be converted to \N

If you need to use the output as input to INFILE, then you should use SELECT INTO OUTFILE. I think this question counts as an XY Problem.

@NoelYap But you're > ${outfile} after confirming that it's equal to /dev/stdout. If you're trying to get CSV form with \N, the recommended way is to use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ....

@Barmar, yes, I did that purposefully and intentionally to make it more obvious the commonality and difference between the then block and the else block. The question is about parameterizing the difference so as to be able to eliminate the if/then/else altogether

@BillKarwin, SELECT … INTO OUTFILE will output the file to the remote machine, not the local one. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2970539/807037

You mention that setting the variable transformer_cmd in a certain way does nor work as expected, but I can't see this variable anywhere in your code. Try to create a small reproducible example, which shows the core issue of your question.

@user1934428, I've edited the question to make it more obvious how I would like transformer_cmd to be used.

If transformer_cmd should act like a no-op in the pipe, you could set it to an array containing only the word cat. A lone cat just copies stdin to stdout, without changing the data.

@user1934428, I've tried cat as transformer_cmd and that failed this requirement. The reason this doesn't work is because mysql must still open up an interactive shell for a "null object" transformer_cmd. This is already described in the question.

I wasn't able to find a suitable transformer_cmd but, based on the hint given by @chepner, I was able to come up with the following:
mysql_cmd "${mysql_args[@]}"

in which mysql_cmd defaults to:
function mysql_cmd() {
  mysql "$@"
}

and if an option were provided to the script, would be overridden to:
function mysql_cmd() {
  mysql "$@" |
    sed -e 's|\\\\|\\|g' |
    tee "${outfile}"
}

