# A one-time generated CSV file in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, generator, irb

Is it possible to create a CSV file right out of the command line in IRB or elsewhere with a one-time use on it. Say, I just need a CSV file with all my user's first name on it.

Can I create that without setting up any architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use Ruby's `csv` library (it's part of the standard lib):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/classes/CSV/Writer.html

Comment: This is amazing! I'm having so much fun. Literally covered in CSV's right now.

Comment: awesome, if `csv` ever falls short for any reason, you can check out `fastercsv` (http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) as well.  I think it's supposed to replace `csv` in ruby 1.9

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using? It seems doubtful that you'd need to use Rails at all.  For example:

[How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)