# mysql delimiter question

Tags: mysql

How do i do this:

```
mysql -u myuser -p mydb -e "select f1,f2 from  mytable" > /tmp/mydata.txt
```

But I want to separate the fields with a comma.

```
mysql --delimiter=, -u myuser -p mydb -e "select f1,f2 from  mytable" > /tmp/mydata.txt
```

Does not work :(

Comment: read the manual about --delimiter option, I don't think it is the correct option you are searching.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't really understand what is the question? Can you explain what you want ?

If your wish is to add delimiter to your output, you have to use **CONCAT_WS** :

```
mysql -u myuser -p mydb -e "select CONCAT_WS(',',f1,f2) from mytable" > /tmp/mydata.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use [INTO OUTFILE](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/)  like this :

```
mysql  -u myuser -p  mydatabase -e 
    "select field1 , field2 FROM mytable INTO OUTFILE 
'/tmp/myfilename.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' "
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT INTO OUTFILE
```

requires ** FILE ** permissions for mysql user https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html (permission to write on mysql host filesystem). It's vulnerability issue and therefore database's ** ALL PRIVILEGES ** not includes FILE permissions.

In most cases better use pipeline replacement from tabulation symbols `\t` to any character you want `,`:

```
mysql -h -p dbname -e 'SELECT * FROM table_name;' | sed 's/\t/,/g' > out.csv
```

Comment: as an alternative to `sed`, you can use `tr '\t' ','`

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the SELECT INTO OUTFILE command to produce your CSV file.  Info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html