# MySQL : XML from a resultset?

Tags: mysql, xml, resultset, record

Is it possible to generate an XML (or csv) string from a resultset in MySQL ?

Basically I'd like to have the contents of an entire record in 1 string...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html) is the documentation for XML, and a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format) to the CSV question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example, you can use [`xml_tag`](http://eriksdiary.blogspot.com/2007/07/xml-output-from-mysql.html) like this:

```
select xml_tag('table',table_name,null,null)
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
```

**Comprehensive Docs:**

- http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html