# Generate CSV based on MySQL query from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

Can I generate a CSV file from phpMyAdmin based on a MySQL query?

For example, let's say I queried a table to return results for the word "image". Could I then produce a CSV with all of the records containing the word "image"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to output MySQL query results in csv format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Comment: This is specific to PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In PhpMyAdmin, go into the SQL tab and enter your query in there. Hit go, then click `Export` at the bottom of your results. You can select to export as a CSV.

In case you're interested, here's how to do it via SQL without PMA: [How to output MySQL query results in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format)

Comment: id does not work for big amount of data, when I click export: No records were selected. I cannot select 20k records because firefox crash(out of mem)

Comment: @user3871754 and for other that encounter this problem, there are 2 export buttons below the results, one that export the selected rows, the other one, in a second bar below, that export everything. It's next to "print" and "copy to clipboard".

Comment: To add to @MarcoMartinelli's helpful comment, the "Export" link you want is located in a box labeled “Query results operations”. (There are at least two other "Export" links on the results page that invoke other behaviors, so it's important to find the right one.) This answer has a helpful screenshot if you're still looking: https://serverfault.com/a/300342/481427

Comment: @SarahLewis great

Answer (score 22):

You may be able to use the [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/select.html)  functionality.  Although this will place the CSV file on the server.  That's a long page, because it's the page for the whole "Select" syntax, but the basics are below:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: This is usually disabled due to security breach.

Answer (score 12):

```
create table tmp_export
SELECT * from table_name WHERE column_name .....
```

It created a table and then I exported the table as CSV. This solution worked fine for me.

Comment: I guess the solution will defiantly work, but it's not a good practice to just create a temp table in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

What also works well is creating a table with the query and then export the table as usual, having all the options of phpmyadmin export available. Simply do something like this in SQL box of phpmyadmin

```
create table tmp_export
select * from xxxx
```

No problems with complex queries and large datasets using this approach.

Answer (score -1):

use adminer, adminer has option to export query results:
https://www.adminer.org/