# How to export query result in a csv file from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running a query in PHPMyAdmin. The query is fine. it's showing the correct result.

I want to export that result in a CSV file. It's not on the local server. It's on the webserver

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM notices
LEFT JOIN companies ON notices.company_number = companies.company_number 
LEFT JOIN sic_codes ON companies.sic_1 = sic_codes.code
LEFT JOIN notice_insolvency_practitioners ON notices.id = notice_insolvency_practitioners.notice_id 
LEFT JOIN insolvency_practitioners ON notice_insolvency_practitioners.insolvency_practitioner_id = insolvency_practitioners.id
Where notices.publication_date >'2020-05-01' and notices.publication_date < '2020-05-31'
```

In the phpmyadmin window at the bottom of the result pane, I can see a export link. but if I click on export that allows me only to export the notice table.

[image]

I don't want to create a frontend window for it. just want to  export the result in CSV file from PHPMyAdmin

How to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239956/generate-csv-based-on-mysql-query-from-phpmyadmin

Comment: Not really. The first answer which has maximum vote I have tried that way. When I click export it immediately picks up one table. I don't want to export one table. I have a specific query which joins result from 4 table.  I don't want to create a temporary table also aswell

Comment: For me it's working. There are no checkboxes, but still i can do export into csv. Exported file has name of single table, but in csv i also have joined columns.

Comment: Have you created a temporary table? Or you edited query to export data in CSV file. I have updated my question. Please have another look. I appreciate your advice. FYI I am running this query in web server. not local server. will the