# MySQLdb to Excel

Tags: python, mysql, django, excel

I have a Django project which has a mysql database backend. How can I export contents from my db to an Excel (xls, xlsx) format?

Comment: export to csv - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356578/how-to-output-mysql-query-results-in-csv-format

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin has an Export tab, and you can export in CSV.  This can be imported into Excel.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how can I directly export xls or xlsx without phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Answer (score 0):

If you need a xlsx (excel 2007) exporter, you can use [openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/). Otherwise [xlwt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) is an option.

Answer (score 0):

[Openpyxl](https://bitbucket.org/ericgazoni/openpyxl/) is a great choice,
but if you don't wanna go through a new thing you can simply write you own exporting function:

for example you can export things in CSV format like this:

```
def CVSExport(database_array):
  f_csv = open('mydatabase.csv', 'w')
  for row in database_array:
    f_csv.write('"%s";;;;;"%s"\n'%(row[0], row[1]))
  f_csv.close()
```

when you open exported file by excel you should set ";;;;;" as separator.